# How to capture a value for later in a nested function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, nested-function

```
def make_functions():
    flist = []

    for i in [1, 2, 3]:
        def print_i():
            print(i)
        flist.append(print_i)

    return flist

functions = make_functions()
for f in functions:
    f()
```

The output of this code is:

```
3
3
3
```

**Questions:**

1. Why does `print_i` only capture the final value of `i`?
2. How can we modify this code to make it print `1, 2, 3`?

One way to answer question #2 is as follows, but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way that captures the value of `i`.

```
def make_functions():
    flist = []

    for i in [1, 2, 3]:
        def print_i(j):
            print(j)
        flist.append((print_i, i))

    return flist

functions = make_functions()
for f, i in functions:
    f(i)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because scope of `i` in your case is of `make_functions`, you should make a separated scope for it, here I wrap it into a function

```
def make_functions():
    flist = []

    for i in [1, 2, 3]:
        def print_i_factory(i):
            def print_i():
                print(i)

            return print_i

        flist.append(print_i_factory(i))

    return flist

functions = make_functions()
for f in functions:
    f()
```

Comment: This makes sense, but if scope of `i` is `make_functions`, how does the code print the last value of `i` (question 1)?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar according to [this](https://docs.python.org/dev/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement),  `for-loop makes assignments to the variables in the target list. This overwrites all previous assignments`, so every `i` in `print_i` of question 1 is referenced to that overwritten value

Comment: Well, that's fine, but as I said in the comment to the other answer, `i` is a local variable in `make_functions`, and shouldn't be available inside the `for` loop after exiting `make_functions`.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611760/scoping-in-python-for-loops) may answer your question

Comment: Specifically, "_Previous proposals to make for-loop variables local to the loop have stumbled on the problem of existing code that relies on the loop variable keeping its value after exiting the loop, and it seems that this is regarded as a desirable feature_". I hate when people play the backward compatibility card and developers bend over backwards to keep doing what's clearly wrong.

Answer (score 4):

1. Like the user above said, the scope of `i` in your case is of `make_function`. So when the functions are executed, they print the value of `i` in that scope, 3. This is because the function is saved with the body `print(i)` without any concept of what `i` is at that moment. `i` is not evaluated until the function is called later on, when `i` is already 3.
2. To answer question 2, we need to get `i` in the scope of the `print_i` function. We can do this with a wrapper function that has `i` as an argument, as the user above did, or much simpler, we can just pass the value of `i` as a default value. Now we are appending 3 different `print(i)` functions, each with its own default value, which is the value of `i` at that moment in the for loop.

```py
def make_functions():
    flist = []

    for i in [1, 2, 3]:
        def print_i(i=i):
            print(i)
        flist.append(print_i)

    return flist

functions = make_functions()
for f in functions:
    f()
```