# Can you make "for" created values be local in python?

Tags: python, for-loop

So like, i'd want

```
i,j = 3,3

for i in range(10):
   j = i

print(i,j)
```

to print me "3 9", but in reality it prints me "9 9".
I'm coming from lua, and this is possible to do since a local variable "i" is automatically created for the cycle, so that there's an "i" that reaches 9 inside the loop, but there's still an "i" outside the loop that's still at 3.

Is this possible? Or do i must use a variable that has not previously been used?

Comment: Have a read of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611760/scoping-in-python-for-loops

Comment: yea, that's exactly the answer i needed, thanks, even though it kind of sucks. i did search for the answer before posting it, but i wasn't aware of what scoping meant, mb.
now... how do i close the post?

Answer (score 1):

You are itself iterating with `i` where it is already declared before with `j` as 3 and in loop, values of both variables increase. So use a different variable. If you add a `print(i,j)` you will see both increase by 1 in each iteration, because `i` is the variable which is used to iterate over the range, so the old `i` value gets overwritten. Perhaps use a different variable like `k` to iterate instead of `i`. Or instead variables have scope, global and local, then use the `global` keyword. List comprehension could be considered.