# Variable in a for loop affects the global variable

Tags: python

I'm quite new to Python and I learned something interesting.

```
item = 5

for item in [1, 2, 3]:
    pass

print(item)
```

Result:

```
3
```

I expected 5 because I thought the variable inside the a for loop would be local to its scope but it wasn't.

I think it is not good since I might accidentally write global variable name in a for loop.

How do people usually deal with the potential problem? Is there a way to make the variable local to the scope?

Comment: Loops don't have their own scope. Python isn't all that odd in that regard. I have never found it to be a problem. It is only a problem if you try to bring scope ideas gleaned from e.g. Java to Python.

Comment: Give them different names and they will be different variables.

Comment: I have never had this problem in other languanges but python. It sucks python doesn't have local variable.

Comment: To be fair, Python is a bit odd. Comprehensions, for example, have their own scope (in Python 3) but `for` loops don't.

Comment: What would be the downside of making the variable local in a for loop. I think it will only be safer.

Comment: @ZackLee Other languages such as JavaScript and PHP support this behaviour too. Python is not the only one. This has been discussed before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611760/scoping-in-python-for-loops

Comment: @ZackLee The downside of making the variable local in a for loop is that it would then be unnecessarily tedious to access its last value after the loop ends, particularly if the loops is ended with a `break` statement.

Comment: @Selcuk This question is basically a duplicate of that other one. Good catch.

Comment: @selcuk In Javascript, i can use 'let' to prevent it from accessing the global variable.

Comment: @ZackLee Python *does have local variables*, it just doesn't have *block scope*.

Comment: If you are worried about a for-loop cluttering your global namespace, your for-loop should probably not be in the global scope to begin with

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Actually all Python variables are local to their code blocks unless declared with `global` or `nonlocal`. It's just that what's considered a code block is different in Python than in some other languages. A module, a function or a class is a code block. A for loop is not.

Comment: @ZackLee Please read: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html

Comment: @blhsing I'm using the word "block" in the sense of the [grammer](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html). The loop body is called a "block". Basically, a block is a continuous section of code indented at the same level. What might often be delimited by curly braces in C-like langauges

Comment: @ZackLee True, but `let` is a recent addition. Similarly comprehensions have their own scope in Python 3. You claimed that no other languages but Python shows this behaviour, but that's not correct (we can also add Ruby to the list).

Comment: @Selcuk I would rather first have constants in Python than block scope. I've never once missed block scope, but I do often wish for constants. Although it isn't clear the best way to allow that to happen. Javascript had variable declarations, which python doesn't have; although, you could probably add a `constant` keyword just like `global`. In any case, originally JS scoping rules were pretty rough in that assignment to variables in a local scope would *default to global* leading to a lot of bugs. Python, famously, has the opposite defaulting to local.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm personally quite happy with the PEP-8 conventions for constants (uppercase names). Scopes are also fine (leaking comprehension variables was a bit weird and fortunately they have fixed that). I am still trying to get over the walrus operator.