# Confused that variables from tuple unpacking in for loop are still defined afterwards

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples

I'm messing around with Tuple unpacking and don't understand why I'm getting the result that I am.

I have a tuple list:

```
tup_list = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
```

and when I do:

```
for a, b, c in tup_list:
    print(a)
    print(c)
```

it returns:

```
1
3
4
6
```

I mostly understand what's going on there, I established a variable for each item in the tuples and told it to print out certain ones.  But when I do:

```
for item in tup_list:
    print(a)
    print(c)
```

it returns:

```
4
6
4
6
```

I have no idea what's happening here. Why am I getting four things returned but two of the are the same?  How does it even know what to do if I haven't defined `a` and `c`?

Comment: That's using values for `a` and `c` from your previous loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scoping in Python 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611760/scoping-in-python-for-loops)

Comment: `a` and `c` retain the last value you assigned to the... and you are simply repeatedly printing those values in a loop. "How does it even know what to do if I haven't defined a and c?" **you absolutely defined those variables**, right here: `for a, b, c in tup_list:`