# Another redeclared variable without usage in PyCharm

Tags: python, scope, pycharm

I've looked at several issues with this topic but I believe this is a new situation. I have this Python code in PyCharm 2022.2.2:

```py
res = []
for i in range(10):
    j = i
    for k in range(4):
        res.append(j)
        j = j + 1
```

On the line `j = 1` PyCharm complains about:

> "Redeclared 'j' defined above without usage".

Obviously `j` is not declared above. Changing the line to `j += 1` the warning disappears.

Is PyCharm confused or am I missing something?

Comment: Is that the only file in the project ? And is that the only code of the file ?

Comment: Yes and yes :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the warning is correct, if you look at scopes:

> [9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=scope#python-scopes-and-namespaces)
>
> (...)
>
> Although scopes are determined statically, they are used dynamically. At any time during execution, there are 3 or 4 nested scopes whose namespaces are directly accessible:
>
> - **the innermost scope**, which is searched first, contains the local names
> - **the scopes of any enclosing functions**, which are searched starting with the nearest enclosing scope, contains non-local, but also non-global names
> - (...)

There's only 1 scope, the outer and inner `for` are both part of the **innermost scope** because they're loops they're not functions nor methods.

> Obviously `j` is not declared above.

`j` is declared in the outer `for` which puts it in the same scope as `i`. See this concise answer in [Scoping in Python 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3611858).

> "Redeclared 'j' defined above without usage".

Here's the trick, the linter is warning you the variable **wasn't used** in the outer `for` loop. What this is saying is that your code isn't *"pythonic"*... A more pythonic way of writing it would be:

```py
res = []
for i in range(10):
    for k in range(i, i+4):
        res.append(k)
```

Here you've gotten rid of the redundant `j` declaration (and the warning). The code becomes much easier to work with because you don't have to consider the additional `j` variable and how its value is changed and shared between the 2 loops. That's what the warning is trying to tell you.

---

**End note about version:**

> but I believe this is a new situation. I have this Python code in PyCharm 2022.2.2:

Correct. I tried it in the older PyCharm 2022.1 and the linter does not emit the warning. So it's a recent change (although I've encountered this warning in other versions under similar circumstances).

Comment: Nice explanation, thanks. Changing the last line to `j += 1` removes the warning, which probably should not be the case.

Comment: @wibek that part is likely a bug, but the warning itself (the meat of the issue) is correct.