# How does indentation affect the scope of the variable inside a for loop in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop

I print an item twice with indentation, and it prints the values of the item
in iterated format. But when I print an item without indentation (I mean after the loop ends) it only prints the last value of item.

Here in the code it is `3`. Why?

```
for item in (1,2,3):
  print(item)
  print(item)
print(item)
```

**output:**

```
1
2
3  
1
2
3
3
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: See [Scoping in 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3611760/2745495)

Comment: That is not the output of that 'for' loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in (1, 2, 3):
    print(item)

print()

print(item)  # this prints 3 because it is the last number item was assigned to

"""
Iteration 1: item = 1
Iteration 2: item = 2
Iteration 3: item = 3
print(item) # prints 3
"""
```

Comment: may I know why  it only takes the last value in the item and python not printing whole value

Comment: @CyberEvil What do you mean by whole value?

Comment: whole value means that  why it doesn't print 1,2,3 for another time

Comment: As I explained at the first iteration, item = 1, then item = 2, then item = 3, never was item equal to (1, 2, 3), so it will not print 1, 2, 3 again. If you want to print it another time you can do this
```for i in range(2): for item in (1, 2, 3): print(item)
```