# Why doesn't Python delete the iterate variable after a loop?

Tags: python, loops, iterator, ipython

I found the situation when running ipython. The version of python is 2.6.6 and ipython 0.13. For example:

```
In [1]: for i in range(100):
   ...:     pass
   ...: 

In [2]: who
Out [2]: i  

In [3]: print i
Out [3]: 99
```

After the loop, the variable `i` still exists. So I want to know is this a bug of Python design? If not, why? Thanks.

Comment: It's not a bug. It is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is not a bug.

The `for` loop does *not* create a new scope. Only functions and modules introduce a new scope, with classes, list/dict/set comprehensions<sup>*</sup>, lambdas and generators being specialized functions when it comes to scoping.

This is documented in the [`for` loop statement documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for):

> The target list is not deleted when the loop is finished, but if the sequence is empty, it will not have been assigned to at all by the loop.

A practical use of this feature is [getting the last item of an iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138873/cleanest-way-to-get-last-item-from-python-iterator):

```
last = defaultvalue
for last in my_iter:
    pass
```

---

<sup>*</sup> List comprehensions in Python 2 work like `for` loops, no new scope, but in Python 3 they, as well as dict and set comprehensions across Python versions, do create a new scope.

Comment: @jamylak: thanks for that reference, that is a nice short illustration of a use case.