# reduce large dataset in python using reduce function

Tags: python, python-3.x, reduce, bigdata

I was trying a simple reduce function on a dataset of 1000000 integers,
Here is what I'm trying to do,

```
from functools import reduce
a = (x for x in range(1,1000000))
reduce(lambda x,y: x*y,a)
```

Problem is, it is taking a lot of time! is there a faster way to implement this size of dataset?

Comment: Tell us more about what you mean by reduce? Is that means you have a list of integers and you want to make separate list of the given list? or anything else. You doesn't sound clear.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here is the size of your result that makes the calculation takes so log. Basically, python can handle numbers as big as your memory will allow which means it's only limited by your memory. And note that as the numbers grow bigger, the cost of all operations on them increases. And as far as I know the `reduce()` function is the most python way for this task. But still since you only want the factorial of a particular number you can just use builtin `math.factorial()` function :
which is by far faster than `reduce()`, and that's because python's `math` module function are implemented in C.

```
In [52]: %timeit math.factorial(10000)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.67 ms per loop

In [53]: %timeit reduce(mul, range(1, 10000))
10 loops, best of 3: 20.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: Can you explain why this is faster than the code that the OP has written?

Comment: You shouldn't create a generator, you could pass 'range(1,1000000)' as an argument to 'accumulate'. accumulate(range(1,1000000), mul)

Comment: how do I get a reduced resultset/ last  value in accumulate

Comment: @OleksandrDashkov Indeed, I just missed that!

Comment: @user2717058 Sorry what you mean by *educed resultset/ last*?

Comment: I'm interested in final result, if there a way to get last value in accumulate? because I was primarily interested in the complete multiplication result

Comment: @user2717058 I suppose you'll find answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3169701/4175590

Comment: @user2717058 Sorry accumulate is not a proper way to go in this case since you only want the latest result. Check out the update.