# Capture Raspicam image via PiCamera module - How to avoid old images?

Tags: python, numpy, camera, iterator, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project where we are using the Raspicam attached to a Raspberry Pi to capture (and process) images with python using the [PiCamera](https://github.com/waveform80/picamera) module.

With our current implementation I am experiencing an unexpected behaviour.
The camera is configured to capture images with 15 frames per second. To simulate processing time the program waits 5 seconds.

Minimal example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cv2
from picamera import PiCamera
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray

class RaspiCamera:

    def __init__(self, width, height, framerate):

        self.camera = PiCamera()
        self.camera.resolution = (width, height)
        self.camera.framerate = framerate
        self.rawCapture = PiRGBArray(self.camera, size=self.camera.resolution)
        self.capture_continuous = self.camera.capture_continuous(self.rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True)

    def capture(self):

        frame = self.capture_continuous.next()
        image = self.rawCapture.array
        self.rawCapture.truncate(0)

        return image

if __name__ == "__main__":

    camera = RaspiCamera(640, 480, 15)
    while True:
        frame = camera.capture()
        cv2.imshow("Image", frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(5000) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
```

When `capture()` is called for the first time, `self.capture_continuous.next()` returns an up to date image. When calling `capture()` consecutively, it often happens that `self.capture_continuous.next()` does not return the latest image but one that is already a few seconds old (verified by pointing the camera at a clock). From time to time, it's even older than 10 seconds. On the other hand, sometimes `self.capture_continuous.next()` actually returns the latest image.

Since `capture_continuous` is an object of the type `generator`, my assumption is that it keeps generating camera images in the background that accumulate in a queue while the program waits and on the next call of `self.capture_continuous.next()` the next element in the queue is returned.

Anyway, I am only interested in the latest, most up to date image the camera has captured.
Some first attempts to get hold of the latest images failed. I tried to call `self.capture_continuous.next()` repeatedly in a while loop to get to the latest image.
Since a generator is apparently also an iterator I tried some methods mentioned in this post: [Cleanest way to get last item from Python iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138873/cleanest-way-to-get-last-item-from-python-iterator).

Simply using the `capture()` function of the `PiCamera` class itself is not an option since it takes approx. 0.3 seconds till the image is captured what is too much for our use case.

Does anyone have a clue what might cause the delay described above and how it could be avoided?

Comment: Have you found a solution? I'm facing a similar problem with this unexpected behavior.