# Stop for loop of generator in second to the last iteration

Tags: python, loops, generator

I have *generator* `cut_slices` and use `for` *loop*. But I need to do some specific work with the first and **last** yielding elements outside the loop. With first it's easy, just use `next()` before loop. But what with **last**?

---

```
fu_a = self.cut_slices(unit, unit_size) #generator (simple for loop with some calculations and yield)

header = self.make_header(p=0, first_byte=unit[0], rtp_type=rtp_type, flag='s')
self.send_packet(header + next(fu_a))

for i in fu_a: #if there is an analogue of a[:-1] for generator object?
    header = self.make_header(p=0, first_byte=unit[0], rtp_type=rtp_type,
                              flag='m')
    self.send_packet(header + i)

header = self.make_header(p=0, first_byte=unit[0], rtp_type=rtp_type, flag='e')
self.send_packet(header + next(fu_a))
```

P.S. I understand that there are other ways to achieve the same result, just want to figure out.

Comment: If you put each element in a variable, so that the variable always has just the last one generated, when the loop is over, ...

Comment: You can keep track of the last item per iteration, so, before next iteration, update last item with current one.

Comment: check [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138873/cleanest-way-to-get-last-item-from-python-iterator) Cleanest way to get last item from Python iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the below code, run your intended function on aa in the for loop, and disregard the last function call. After the end of loop, you'll have your variable as `aa`

```
In [1]: a = (i for i in range(10))
In [2]: first = next(a)
In [3]: first
Out[3]: 0
In [4]: for aa in a:
   ...:     print(aa)
   ...:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
In [5]: aa
Out[5]: 9
```

After reading a medium article on a similar topic, I found a better way to get the last val:

```
In [29]: def get_last_val(A):
    ...:     v = next(A)
    ...:     for a in A:
    ...:         yield False, v
    ...:         v = a
    ...:     yield True, v

In [30]: a = (i for i in range(10))

In [31]: a = get_last_val(a)

In [32]: for aa in a:
    ...:     print(aa)
    ...:
(False, 0)
(False, 1) 
(False, 2)
(False, 3)
(False, 4)
(False, 5)
(False, 6)
(False, 7)
(False, 8)
(True, 9)
```

If the first return value is True, that would be the last value in the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't cause memory problems, just make a list of everything returned by the generator, and slice that.

```
fu_a = self.cut_slices(unit, unit_size) #generator (simple for loop with some calculations and yield)

header = self.make_header(p=0, first_byte=unit[0], rtp_type=rtp_type, flag='s')
self.send_packet(header + next(fu_a))

*middle_fu, last_fu = list(fu_a)

for i in middle_fu:
    header = self.make_header(p=0, first_byte=unit[0], rtp_type=rtp_type,
                              flag='m')
    self.send_packet(header + i)

header = self.make_header(p=0, first_byte=unit[0], rtp_type=rtp_type, flag='e')
self.send_packet(header + last_fu)
```