# Specify the last index of list or dictionary by enumerate function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, enumerate

As we know that enumerate function can be use to find the in index of a value in list or hashmap. My question is can we specify the ending index of list. As the code is provided if anyone can help me to solve this problem. I will be very thankful to him

`[i for i, key in enumerate(sorted_d) if key[1] == sortedVotes[0][0]]`

Answer (score 0):

you can use a list slice.

```
ending_index = 5
[i for i, key in enumerate(sorted_d[:ending_index+1]) if key[1] == sortedVotes[0][0]]
```

I added 1 because the end of a slice is not inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'ending index of list'? If index of last element, then you may use

```
i_last = len(sorted_d) - 1
```

If you want to obtain the last item specially from 'enumerate' you may use the following code

```
i_last, value_last = None, None
for i_last, value_last in enumerate(sorted_d):
    pass
```

[Cleanest way to get last item from Python iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138873/cleanest-way-to-get-last-item-from-python-iterator)