# Python Loop While cumulative sum less than 100

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, infinite-loop, break

```
> num = 0
total = 0

while(True):
    num += 1
    total += num
    if total < 100:
        break
     
print('The last number is %d and total is %d' % (num, total))
```

The answer is supposed to be "The last number is 13 and total is 91" but I keep getting 1 for the answers. I know there's something wrong with the sixth line but I can't figure out how to make it right.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What is your question?  Please include enough details (specifically any code or errors you have).

Comment: sorry i'm new here so still a bit confused

Comment: Please include that in your post and not in the comments.

Comment: your ```if total < 100:``` isn't correct.   You need to break when total >= 100

Comment: I got 14 instead of 13 as the answer. What could be wrong?

Comment: The reason is the loop needed to add the extra values before it detects that ```total``` > 100.

Comment: Ahhh I see! Thanks a lot for the answers it helped a lot!

Comment: Is there any reason you have `> num = 0` at the start instead of `num = 0` @newbiepythoner ?

Comment: Oh sorry I think I might have mistyped it!

Answer (score 2):

Even with the fix of `if total >= 100: break` you'll always get one higher number (and total) than the limit. That's because `total` is first assigned and then checked. So it's *assigned* `105` with number being `14` and then checked to see if it exceeds `100`.

Two changes:

1. check what `total` *would be* before assigning it.
2. check this potential value of total at the *start* of the loop

```py
num = 0
total = 0
while True:
    if total + num + 1 > 100:
        break
    num += 1
    total += num

print(f'The last number is {num} and total is {total}')
# The last number is 13 and total is 91
```

And using an [*Assignment Expression* (aka Walrus operator)](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#syntax-and-semantics) you can reduce the re-calculation by assigning checked value to the next possible total:

```py
num = 0
total = 0
while True:
    if (next_total := total + num + 1) > 100:
        break
    num += 1
    total = next_total  # don't add, just assign

print(num, total)  # the values are more important than printing
# 13 91
```

---

Edit: **More advanced** ways to do it using functional programming:

```py
from itertools import accumulate, count, takewhile

result = list(takewhile(lambda t: t < 100, accumulate(count(1))))
print(result)  # output for sanity
# [1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, 66, 78, 91]
print(len(result), result[-1])  # num and total
# 13 91
```

or

```py
from itertools import accumulate, count, takewhile

result = list(enumerate(takewhile(lambda t: t < 100, accumulate(count(1))), start=1))
print(result)  # output for sanity
# [(1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 6), (4, 10), (5, 15), (6, 21), (7, 28), (8, 36), (9, 45), (10, 55), (11, 66), (12, 78), (13, 91)]
print(result[-1])  # each element is tuple of num and total
# (13, 91)
```

This second functional option appears longer, so why use it? It can be combined with a [`deque` of size 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3169701/1431750) so that the `result` list never needs to be stored, only calculated. And when the list isn't stored, we wouldn't know it's length `len()`. So that *index* comes from [`enumerate(..., start=1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate). Without needing to store the list, it can be used for huge numbers without running out of RAM.

```py
from collections import deque
from itertools import accumulate, count, takewhile

# items below is an iterable, not the actual list
items = enumerate(takewhile(lambda t: t < 100, accumulate(count(1))), start=1)
print(items)
# <enumerate object at 0x0000024F9CCBB5C0>
dd = deque(items, maxlen=1)
last_element = dd.pop()
print(last_element)  # tuple of num & total
# (13, 91)
```

And with a huge limit:

```py
def largest_until_total(limit):
    items = enumerate(takewhile(lambda t: t < limit, accumulate(count(1))), start=1)
    return deque(items, maxlen=1).pop()

print(largest_until_total(1_000_000_000_000))  # 1 trillion
# (1414213, 999999911791)
print(largest_until_total(1_000_000_000_000_000))  # 1 quadrillion
# (44721359, 999999997764120)
```

However, if you really wanted to use this for very large limits, it would be better to reverse engineer it with the ["sum of first N natural numbers"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) formula `N * (N+1) / 2`

Comment: Better readable: `if total + num + 1 > 100:` could be written as `if total + num >= 100:`.

Comment: @Matthias I agree with that but it _hides_ the off-by-one problem for newer users. The `+ 1` makes the intent clearer. Also, that the `+ 1` is actually for `num`, ie `num + 1` which is the next number being added.

Comment: Great answer @aneroid, I'm just curious, is the any reason to modify the OP's `print` statement? And did you use the *python* interpreter syntax because OP used it as well? Personally I prefer it when it's written in a simple format that can be copy pasted in an online compiler to test it out quickly.

Comment: @Liam The answer to the first two question is related: I did it in Python REPL (if that's what you meant by _"python interpreter syntax"_) so `print`'ing is not required to see the result. I'll edit the question to remove the REPL bits.

Comment: @aneroid Lovely answer, although one suggestion (edit queue is full). I'd change `print(num, total)` to `print('The last number is %d and total is %d' % (num, total))` to keep the print statement closer to the OP's code.

Comment: @Liam Ok, I've edited only the first print to show the same output as the OP. I generally don't bother with such `print`s unless it's important to the answer, such as formatting or alignment. What's more important is the actual values of `num` and `total`. Once they have the result, they can do what they want with it - print or log, etc. is unrelated. And having excessive prints can sometimes make the important details harder to see. Like in `print(f'The last number is {result[-1][0]} and total is {result[-1][1]}')`. And print's hide the actual type of the data; like in the tuples above.

Comment: I totally agree @aneroid, I appreciate you taking the time to edit your answer, I've deleted mine and upvoted yours, as a result since yours is better anyways. Thank you for being so kind and patient

Answer (score 0):

Comments should be description enough.

```
def max_sum(m):
    t, n = 0, 2
    while True:
        #linear sum
        t_ = int((n+1)*(n/2))
        #adjust num based on current condition
        n += (t_<m)
        n -= (t_>m)
        #store or print respectively
        if t_<m: t = t_
        else:
            print(f'num is {n} total is {t}')
            break

max_sum(100)
```