# Python how to store last element in yield iterator?

Tags: python, iterator, zlib

I have the following code:

```
import zlib


def inflate(infile):
    data = infile.read()
    offset = 0
    while offset < len(data):
        window = data[offset : offset + 2]
        for key, value in zlib_headers.items():
            if window == key:
                decomp_obj = zlib.decompressobj()
                yield key, offset, decomp_obj.decompress(data[offset:])
        if offset == len(data):
            break
        offset += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    zlib_headers = {b"\x78\x01": 3, b"\x78\x9c": 6, b"\x78\xda": 9}

    with open("input_file", "rb") as infile:
        *_, last = inflate(infile)

    key, offset, data = last
    start_offset = offset + len(zlib.compress(data, zlib_headers[key]))

    print(start_offset)
```

Below the function, I'm printing information generated from the iterator. As you can see, I'm doing so for each one, but I only need to do that for the last one. How can I do this? I still need the function to work as a generator using "yield."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cleanest way to get last item from Python iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138873/cleanest-way-to-get-last-item-from-python-iterator)

Comment: I saw this, but I was a little confused as to what this would look like in my code. I couldn't get it to work. Do you mind showing me what my code what look like doing this?

Comment: What is the__purpose__ of `inflate` function and the multi-case print in main? There could be a simpler solution to evaluate the compression-level based on the [zlib magic headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17176881/5730279) (i.e. your `ZLIB_MARKERS`). Can you clarify the use-case and if we can adjust the `inflate` method for a better solution, please.

Comment: The inflate function reads a file at every two bytes and decompresses if one of the headers in ZLIB_MARKERS is read. It's necessary that the header is known for re-compression (it has to use the same compression method). Basically, the reason I asked this question is because I use that function to determine the beginning offset after the final zlib compressed section. This function's usage should still work as a zlib decompresser, though, as I'm also using it for that. I'll update the function as I've optimized it a bit, but feel free to improve on it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on, you could do something like this. Different from [Cleanest way to get last item from Python iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138873/cleanest-way-to-get-last-item-from-python-iterator), you need to unpack the last item as well, since the yield returns 3 values, which are packed into a tuple, because they are assigned to a single variable `last`:

```
def inflate():
    """mock function to yield 3 values"""
    for i in range(10):
        yield i, 10 + i, 20 + i

# With unpacking
*_, last = inflate()
marker_index, offset, data = last
print(marker_index, offset, data)

# With for loop
for last in inflate():
    pass
marker_index, offset, data = last
print(marker_index, offset, data)
```

Comment: Alright, thank you. This works perfectly. Just out of curiosity, is there a reason to choose one method over the other? Which would you choose? Is one more efficient than the other?

Comment: @4xZnskJp I can't really say if there is any substantial difference, besides looks, so I would pick the one I think reads easier. If you want to dive more into all the different ways this can be done and their pros and cons, I suggest you check out the linked thread.