# Read specific bytes using urlopen()

Tags: python, urllib2

I want to read specific bytes from a remote file using a python module. I am using urllib2. Specific bytes in the sense bytes in the form of `Offset`,`Size`. I know we can read X number of bytes from a remote file using `urlopen(link).read(X)`. Is there any way so that I can read data which starts from `Offset` of length `Size`.?

```
def readSpecificBytes(link,Offset,size):
# code to be written
```

Comment: What about: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299213/python-how-can-i-open-a-file-and-specify-the-offset-in-bytes ?

Comment: Or perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17643851/downloading-a-portion-of-a-file-using-http-requests

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1798945/153861 for a possible solution (read the full answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work with many servers (Apache, etc.), but doesn't always work, esp. not with dynamic content like CGI (*.php, *.cgi, etc.):

```
import urllib2
def get_part_of_url(link, start_byte, end_byte):
    req = urllib2.Request(link)
    req.add_header('Range', 'bytes=' + str(start_byte) + '-' + str(end_byte))
    resp = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    content = resp.read()
```

Note that this approach means that the server never has to send and you never download the data you don't need/want, which could save *tons* of bandwidth if you only want a small amount of data from a large file.

When it doesn't work, just read the first set of bytes before the rest.

See [Wikipedia Article on HTTP headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#range-request-header) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the *file-like* object returned by urllib2.urlopen() doesn't actually have a `seek()` method. You will need to work around this by doing something like this:

```
def readSpecificBytes(link,Offset,size):
    f = urllib2.urlopen(link)
    if Offset > 0:
        f.read(Offset)
    return f.read(size)
```

Comment: Note that for very large files this will be a fairly expensive method. You'll have to download all of the content up to this point.