# Python read file from the end, it's a large file,cannot read into memory

Tags: python, file, logging

How to read the file from the file at the end DESC?
For example

filename:test

content:

```
11111111
22222222
333333333
```

---

```
fp = open('test', 'r')
print fp.readline
```

---

```
333333333
22222222
11111111
```

it is a large file,i do not want to read all content out.

Comment: Google can find this answer faster than I can type it out

Comment: As @JustinJasmann pointed out, google is your friend. LMGTFY: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3568833/how-to-read-lines-from-a-file-in-python-starting-from-the-end

Comment: How much memory do you have? If the file fits in memory, just do `lines = list(fp); lines.reverse()`.

Comment: `with open ('egal.py') as f: print list(f)[::-1]`

Comment: it is a large file,i do not want to read all content out.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Reading line from the end which is relatively tidious process,

you can use reversed() function as follows..

```
with open(filename, 'r') as fheader:  
    for line in reversed(fheader.readlines()):  
         print line
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in open(r'C:\test.txt').readlines()[::-1]:
    print x
```

Comment: it is a large file,i do not want to read all content out.

Answer (score 0):

We discussed the same problem in the [China Python User Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/python-cn) just a few month ago. The some of the answers are copied from our discussion.

No matter what solution you choose, the essential is same: seek to the end of the file, read a block of data, find the last line breaker(\r\n or \n), get the last line, seek backwards, and do the same thing again and again.

You can try to preprocess the file with `tail -n`, it is efficient(implemented in C) and is designed for this job.
Check its [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c) if you want to implement it yourself.

or call the same command in Python:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
txt = Popen(['tail', '-n%d' % n, filename], stdout=PIPE).communitate()[0]
;)
```

or try a pure python solution:

```
def last_lines(filename, lines = 1):
    #print the last several line(s) of a text file
    """
    Argument filename is the name of the file to print.
    Argument lines is the number of lines to print from last. 
    """
    block_size = 1024
    block = ''
    nl_count = 0
    start = 0
    fsock = file(filename, 'rU')
    try:
        #seek to end
        fsock.seek(0, 2)
        #get seek position 
        curpos = fsock.tell()
        while(curpos > 0): #while not BOF
            #seek ahead block_size+the length of last read block
            curpos -= (block_size + len(block));
            if curpos < 0: curpos = 0 
            fsock.seek(curpos)
            #read to end
            block = fsock.read()
            nl_count = block.count('\n')
            #if read enough(more)
            if nl_count >= lines: break 
        #get the exact start position
        for n in range(nl_count-lines+1):
            start = block.find('\n', start)+1 
    finally:        
        fsock.close()
    #print it out  
    print block[start:] 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    last_lines(sys.argv[0], 5) #print the last 5 lines of THIS file
```