# Python Read Large Text Files

Tags: python, file, file-io

I was trying to compare two large text files line by line (10GB each) without loading the entire files into memory. I used the following code as indicated in other [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475328/read-large-text-files-in-python-line-by-line-without-loading-it-in-to-memory):

```
with open(in_file1,"r") as f1, open(in_file2,"r") as f2:
    for (line1, line2) in zip(f1, f2):
        compare(line1, line2)
```

But it seems that python fails to read the file line by line. I observed the memory usage while running the code is > 20G. I also tried using:

```
import fileinput
for (line1, line2) in zip(fileinput.input([in_file1]),fileinput.input([in_file2])):
    compare(line1, line2)
```

This one also tries to load everything into memory. I'm using Python 2.7.4 on Centos 5.9, and I didn't store any of the lines in my code.

What was going wrong in my code? How should I change it to avoid loading everything into RAM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python's **[zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)** function returns a *list* of tuples. So if fetches the complete files to build this list. Use **[itertools.izip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip)** instead. It will return an *iterator* of tuples.

```
with open(in_file1,"r") as f1, open(in_file2,"r") as f2:
    for (line1, line2) in izip(f1, f2):
        compare(line1, line2)
```