# Count columns of gzipped tsv without loading

Tags: python

I have a large tab-delimited file that has been gzipped, and I would like to know how many columns it has. For small files I can just unzip and read into python, for large files this is slow. Is there a way to count the columns quickly without loading the file into python?

[Effeciently counting number of columns of text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004180/effeciently-counting-number-of-columns-of-text-file) is almost identical, but since my files are gzipped just reading the first line won't work. Is there a way to make python efficiently unzip just enough to read the first line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... but since my files are gzipped just reading the first line won't work.

Yes it will.

```
import csv
import gzip

with gzip.open('file.tsv.gz', 'rt') as gzf:
    reader = csv.reader(gzf, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    print(len(next(reader)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with traditional unix command line tools. For example:

```
$ zcat file.tsv.gz | head -n 1 | tr $'\t' '\n' | wc -l
```

zcat (or gunzip -c) unzips and outputs to standard output, without modifying the file. 'head -n 1' reads exactly one line and outputs it. The 'tr' command replaces tabs with newlines, and 'wc -l' counts the number of lines. Because 'head -n 1' exits after one line, this has the effect of terminating the zcat command as well. It's quite fast. If first line of the file is a header, simply omit the 'wc -l' to see what the headers are.