# How can I check each row of a large csv and write the row if a certain column contains a certain value?

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a large (3.5GB) .csv file that I can't process entirely in memory and want to:

- Read in one row of data
- Check if a field is equal to a given criteria
- If true, append that row to new .csv file. If false, skip to next row
- Loop until end of original file is reached

The end result would be a separate .csv containing all the rows that matched the criteria.

Comment: please provide the code you have already written so we can help you get it right.

Comment: [Read large text files in Python, line by line without loading it in to memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475328/read-large-text-files-in-python-line-by-line-without-loading-it-in-to-memory)

Comment: Welcome friend. To make your question understandable and "attractive" for people that want to help, please consider posting any code you have tried so far, a few representative lines of the *.csv you are trying to parse, your criteria for getting the line, etc. Put some effort into it..

Comment: The standard way of accessing CSV files in Python will probably work just fine - why don't you give that a go and see if you get stuck anywhere?

Comment: `pd.read_csv` has a chunk parameter that allows you to read a file part by part. You can increase the chunk size based on your memory. Reading it into a dataframe and then filtering it, and combining in the end might be more efficient then reading line by line. If you provide a small sample it would be easier to illustrate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the following worked for me. Note that this also produced a separate output file for each criteria value in the list.

```
import csv

# criteria is the column number from the source data to check against the values list
criteria = 4

valueslist= ['criteria1','criteria2','criteria3']

for item in valueslist:

    with open('sourcedata.csv', 'rb') as inf, open(item + '.csv','wb') as outf:
        reader = csv.reader(inf)
        writer = csv.writer(outf)

        # -- Write Headers as first row
        writer.writerow(["column1", "column2", "column3"])
        for row in reader:
            if row[criteria] == item:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way:

```
chunksize = 10**6 // 2  # you may want to adjust it ... 
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    (chunk.query('condition1 & condition2 & ... ')
          .to_csv('output.csv', mode='a', index=False))
```

The trick is `mode='a'` parameter which will instruct pandas to **add** rows instead of overwriting the CSV file...

Answer (score 1):

Try the code below. Set appropriate number of records (that your machine allows) as chunk size.

```
chunksize = 10 ** 5
for chunk in pd.read_csv(filename, chunksize=chunksize):
    df=df.append (chunk [chunk.field==criterion])
```