# Using yield for file handling?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know whether it is a good practice to use yield for file handling,

So currently I use a function f()

f which iterates over a list of file objects and yields the file object.

```py
files = []
for myfile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.ext')):
    f = open(myfile, 'r')
    files.append(f)

def f():
    for f_obj in files:
        yield f_obj
        f_obj.close()

for f_obj in f():
    // do some processing on file.
```

Is this a proper way of handling files in Python ?

Comment: What is `files`? Is it a list of strings (file paths) or are they already open file objects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate over the file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733419/how-to-iterate-over-the-file-in-python)

Comment: They are open file objects, I want to know whether it's safe to use yield like this, since the function f is suspended and it returns back to the next line.

Comment: This is too vague. I'd be a lot more worried about where you get `files` from, and how you manage the resources (as well as why you have an iterable of open handles in the first place).

Comment: As in say, files is a list of open file objects which I took by walking through a directory. I've added it to the code.

Comment: Note that in your code example, I believe `f_obj.close()` is only called for the first `f_obj` once the second `f_obj` is retrieved. So the last of your opened files will never be closed if you don't completely empty the generator. I have not tested this claim.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reading a text file (eg CSV) the yield is quite appropriate to make your source a generator. A bit of a problem with your code is that `f_obj` is very generic, so that you do no accomplish as much with `f()` function.

I simple example with `yield` is reading CSV file - `lines()` turn you filename into a stream of individual lines. Similar thing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38584494/python-generator-to-read-large-csv-file) (aims to keep less data in memory).

```
import csv 

def lines(path):
    with open(path, 'r', newline='') as f:
        for line in csv.reader(f):
            yield line

from pathlib import Path
Path("file.txt").write_text("a,1,2\nb,20,40") 

gen = lines("file.txt")
print(next(gen))
print(next(gen))
```

In a generic way you originally present use of `yield` I think it lack intent and confuses a code reader why this is being done, but that is subjective.

Comment: What about binary files? Why are they not appropriate?

Comment: Why would't they be? My point is that with a binary file you would be opening it with 'rb', and dealing with item delimiters in a different way. I do not have an immidiate example of a sequence from  binary file one may wrap into a generator, but that surely can be a case.