# Changing the default separator in csv created with "gdal_translate -of XYZ"

Tags: python, csv, gdal

I have 100s of .tiff files, and using the following command:

```
gdal_translate -of XYZ MCD13A2.t201624.006.global.1km_NDVI.O0.tif MCD13A2.t201624.006.global.1km_NDVI.O0.csv
```

This generates a .csv file but it is space separated, instead of comma separated.

Does anybody knows why this is happening, or have any solution for converting this space separated file into a comma separated .csv?

Comment: You should provide a bit more informations about your case. For example the command or code you had try, the version of libraries. More details more possibilities that someone can help you quick.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the files? Are these standard CSV files that you downloaded from somewhere or your own files?
By the way a simple find and replace should solve your problem.

Comment: @PiyushShrivastava  m downloading tiff from ftp server then converting it into csv using gdal

Comment: @MarioSantini i have return the command " gdal_translate -of XYZ MCD13A2.t201624.006.global.1km_NDVI.O0.tif MCD13A2.t201624.006.global.1km_NDVI.O0.csv"

Comment: @gauravsingh actually a *space separated values* file is exactly the same forma as the *comma separated values*. The fact that is called *csv* has nothing to do with the fact that it has to be separated by a comma. I'm not an expert of *gdal_translate*, so I could not point you in the right direction, just suggest you to check the tool options or your environment.

Comment: "The fact that is called csv has nothing to do with the fact that it has to be separated by a comma. " What does "comma" in "comma separated values" stand for ?

Comment: From wiki : "In addition, the term "CSV" also denotes some closely related delimiter-separated formats that use different field delimiters. These include tab-separated values and space-separated values. A delimiter that is not present in the field data (such as tab) keeps the format parsing simple. These alternate delimiter-separated files are often even given a .csv extension despite the use of a non-comma field separator."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [google search](http://www.spatialguru.com/gdal-rasters-from-irregular-point-or-ascii-data/) revealed the following approach:

After you are done with the xyz conversion, you can just use the commandline utility `sed` (suppose you use `linux`):

`sed 's/ /,/g' in.xyz > out.csv`

Since you are creating 100s of csv files, you are probably using `gdal_translate` inside a for loop, so you can just add that additional line right after `gdal_translate` and you won't even notice anything!

Still, if you want to use @iFlo's method without worrying about out-of-memory problems, you can have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475328/read-large-text-files-in-python-line-by-line-without-loading-it-in-to-memory).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the CSV module :

```
import csv

with open(ur_infile) as fin, open(ur_outfile, 'w') as fout:
    o=csv.writer(fout)
    for line in fin:
        o.writerow(line.split())
```

It will automatically read your CSV with space separator and write it with comma (by default).

Also, you could specify delimiter like that :

```
csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
```

Comment: file is to big....and have 100s of csv comma separated file each file have 30 milln records ....

Comment: You should write a complete question then.