# Python, how can I set iterator of enumerate to 0 while reading same file again and again

Tags: python, loops

```
with open("...txt") as fp: 
    for i, line in enumerate(fp): 
        if some condition : 
            i=0
            fp.seek(0)
```

---

Text is huge, GBs of data so I use enumerate. I need to process this huge file several thousands of time so I decided to open it just at first time for efficiency. However although this code works, `i` does not become 0 and it just goes on incrementing. I need that to be zero because I need position of lines `i`. And it is just inefficient to multiply billions*several thousands everytime and make some modular arithmetic.

So my question is how can I set `i` to be zero when I go back to the beginning of file? Thanks in advance (I use python 3.6)

Comment: You may want to look into doing a nested loop rather than a loop with them on the same line if you want them to count separately

Comment: If you want to reset `i` to zero part way through your loop, don't use `enumerate`. Increment and reset `i` manually.

Comment: If you are looking to read very large files, you can just iterate over each line per this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475328/read-large-text-files-in-python-line-by-line-without-loading-it-in-to-memory. Furthermore,

Comment: however i tested some speed and reading every line one by one is slower and this enumerate is faster. Isn't there any way to set it to 0?

Comment: You should also test the current approach and closing the file instead of seeking.

Comment: code is already ready with closing and opening everytime and it is just slow. So i want to test with going back to beginning approach and this question is actually for testing how it will improve speed. But i am stuck in that 'i'

Comment: enumerate is a generator function. It's "exhausted" by the time it completes. This is also why you can't just "reset" it. Here is the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/) on enumerate.

Comment: ok thank you, if you write as answer i will accept it. and thank you all for answers

Comment: @xcvbnm I set the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comment, `enumerate` is a generator function. It's "exhausted" by the time it completes. This is also why you can't just "reset" it. Here is the [PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/) on enumerate to further explain how it works.

Furthermore, as also indicated in the comments, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475328/read-large-text-files-in-python-line-by-line-without-loading-it-in-to-memory) post provides the typical way to handle large files.

Answer (score 3):

You *could* always make your own resettable enumerator, but there are probably better ways to do what you really want to do.

Still, here's what a resettable enumerator looks like:

```
 def reset_enumerate(thing, start=0):
     x = start
     for t in thing:
         val = yield t, x
         if val is not None:
             x = val
         else:
             x += 1
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
r = reset_enumerate(range(10))
for i, num in r:
    print('i:', i, 'num:', num)     
    if i == 5:
        i, num = r.send(0)
        print('i:', i, 'num:', num)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you can emulate a scenario like yours:

Assuming i have a file called  `input.txt` with this kind of data:

```
1
2
3
```

Code:

```
j = 0
with open('input.txt', 'r') as f:
    for k in f:
        # A break condition
        # If not we'll face an infinite loop
        if j > 4:
            break
        if k.strip() == '2':
            f.seek(0)
            print("Return to position 0")
            # Don't forget to increment j 
            # Otherwise, we'll end up with an infinite loop
            j += 1
        print(k.strip())
```

Will output:

```
1
Return to position 0
2
1
Return to position 0
2
1
Return to position 0
2
1
Return to position 0
2
1
Return to position 0
2
```