# Replace words of a long document in Python

Tags: python, string, replace, split

I have a dictionary `dict` with some words (2000) and I have a huge text, like Wikipedia corpus, in text format. For each `word` that is both in the dictionary and in the text file, I would like to replace it with `word_1`.

```
with open("wiki.txt",'r') as original, open("new.txt",'w') as mod:
    for line in original:
        new_line = line
        for word in line.split():
            if (dict.get(word.lower()) is not None):
                new_line = new_line.replace(word,word+"_1")           
        mod.write(new_line)
```

This code creates a new file called `new.txt` with the words that appear in the dictionary replaced as I want.

This works for short files, but for the longer that I am using as input, it "freezes" my computer.

Is there a more efficient way to do that?

Edit for Adi219:

Your code seems working, but there is a problem:
if a line is like that: `Albert is a friend of Albert`  and in my dictionary I have `Albert`, after the for cycle, the line will be like this:`Albert_1_1 is a friend of Albert_1`. How can I replace only the exact word that I want, to avoid repetitions like `_1_1_1_1`?

Edit2:
To solve the previous problem, I changed your code:

```
with open("wiki.txt", "r") as original, open("new.txt", "w") as mod:
    for line in original:
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            if dict.get(word.lower()) is not None:
                mod.write(word+"_1 ")
            else:
                mod.write(word+" ")
        mod.write("\n")
```

Now everything should work

Comment: It is hard to say whether a different strategy would be more efficient or not. I think you might want to find out what the problem actually is. Use timeit and some memory profiler.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read large text files in Python, line by line without loading it in to memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475328/read-large-text-files-in-python-line-by-line-without-loading-it-in-to-memory)

Comment: People looking for dataframe can do the same as `dataframe.replace(replace_what, replace_with)`. See [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) for documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

1. You could remove the declaration of `new_line`. Then, change `new_line = new_line.replace(...)` line with `line = line.replace(...)`. You would also have to `write(line)` afterwards.
2. You could add `words = line.split()` and use `for word in words:` for the `for` loop, as this removes a call to `.split()` for every iteration through the words.
3. You could (manually(?)) split your large `.txt` file into multiple smaller files and have multiple instances of your program running on each file, and then you could combine the multiple outputs into one file. Note: You would have to remember to change the filename for each file you're reading/writing to.

So, your code would look like:

```
with open("wiki.txt", "r") as original, open("new.txt", "w") as mod:
    for line in original:
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
            if dict.get(word.lower()) is not None:
                line = line.replace(word, word + "_1")
        mod.write(line)
```

Comment: Your code seems working, but there is a problem. I updated the question, can you take a look?