# MemoryError reading Sql file in Python3.6

Tags: python

I’m getting a MemoryError when I try to read a large sql file in Python3.6 with this command:

```
with open(sql_file, ‘r’) as f:
```

Is there an alternative to this so I can correctly read my sql file ?

Comment: Is it _that_ line that causes the error, or lines inside the `with`block where you actually get the contents of the file?

Comment: No it is exactly that line

Comment: Just opening the file is very unlikely to cause a memory error (a file pointer is only a few bytes), unless you already ate all your memory _before_ this line.

Comment: Is your sql file a query or a data file? How big is the file and how much RAM is installed on your machine?

Comment: Also this as absolutely NOTHING to do with sql nor postgres.

Comment: My sql file is a dump of a database so there is table creation and value insertion in it

Comment: Ok: what format is that dump? (consider adding some lines of your dump to the question)

Comment: use a memory mapped file in python or read it line by line https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475328/read-large-text-files-in-python-line-by-line-without-loading-it-in-to-memory

Comment: Another option is to import it to RDBMS engine and connect python to the database engine

Answer (score 0):

If you have the sql file you should import it into a database and than use a library like [MySQLdb](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html) for python to make your database requests.

I would guess, that opening sql files directly is a good solution. If you want to work with files, I think csv files are the better solution.

Comment: Not the specific problem, but a better solution at all. It is obvious that large file needs more memory. To AVOID problems, it is a good way to give a person the opportunity to find a better solution.

Comment: I need to create the database with python, i’m using psycopg2 to make the link between python and the postgres database. I also get a memoryerror when I execute the sql file with psycopg2 function directly.