# yield n files from disk

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, yield-keyword

I am trying to read file from the disk and then split it into `[features and labels]`

```
def generator(data_path):
   x_text=[]
   counter=0
   _y=[]
   for root, dirs, files in os.walk(data_path):
       for _file in files:
           if _file.endswith(".txt"):
               _contents = list(open(data_path+_file, "r", encoding="UTF8",errors='ignore').readlines())
               _contents = [s.strip() for s in _contents]
               x_text=x_text+_contents

               y_examples=[0,0,0]
               y_examples[counter]=1
               y_labels = [y_examples for s in _contents]
               counter+=1

               _y=_y+y_labels

   return [x_text, _y]
```

I have huge 3.5GB of data in the disk and I cant read it into the memory at the same time. How can I modify this code to generate n files at a time for processing.

```
for X_batch, y_batch in generator(data_path):
         feed_dict = {X: X_batch, y: y_batch}
```

Is there an more efficient way to read this huge data in tensorflow?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475328/read-large-text-files-in-python-line-by-line-without-loading-it-in-to-memory

Comment: The question shouldn't be about efficiency.  It's about whether the tensorflow model can work with the data in pieces, or must it have all the data in memory at once.

Comment: @hpaulj Can you please guide me how to approach this problem(perhaps a tutorial). I am new to tensorflow