# Split JSON file

Tags: python

I have a JSON file (api.json) with list of dictionaries from API like that:

```
[
{
    "column1": "value1",
    "column2": "value2",
    "column3": "value3"
},
{
    "column1": "value4",
    "column2": "value5",
    "column3": "{'something':'something'}"
},
{
    "column1": "value7",
    "column2": "value8",
    "column3": "value9"
},
]
```

Every dictionary in the list represents one row in database.
The list is large in size and I don't want to load it to memory. How do I split the file into multiple smaller files(without going to bash) - each containing a list of no more than 1000 dictionaries?
According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6475340/8156638 I can read the file line by line but how do split it?

PS When I try to use json.load() I get MemoryError

Comment: You need a streaming json parser - [here](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/) is the first one I found (I haven't tried it personally though).

Comment: Yes, streaming parser sounds right for the job. However I can't seem to make it split the file. I've also found another parser "yajl-py" but I need to read the docs first.

Answer (score 1):

Split by keeping the structure.

You have an Array, denoted by the outer square brackets: []

Then, you have objects, denoted but the curly brackets: {}

Split into different files, by creating different arrays:

**File A:**

```
[
  {
    "column1": "value1",
    "column2": "value2",
    "column3": "value3"
  },
  {
    "column1": "value4",
    "column2": "value5",
    "column3": "{'something':'something'}"
  }
]
```

**File B:**

```
[
  {
    "column1": "value7",
    "column2": "value8",
    "column3": "value9"
  }
]
```

Then, you can read each file, and they will be correct.

Comment: Yes. That much I figured. The question is what code can split file this way.