# Python efficiency check

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a text file to parse line by line using python. I read the file as below,

```
with open(filename) as f:
    soup = bs(f.read(),"html.parser")
```

then I split all the lines of the text file into a list.

```
allLine = soup.text.split("\r\n")
```

Now I am iterating the list one by one such as below,

Method 1:

```
for line in allLine:
    # my task
```

My questing is, I can do the same iterating without storing the data into 
list also as below,

Method 2:

```
for line in soup.text.split("\r\n")
        # my task
```

My Questions is,

Method 1 allocating extra spaces for the list '`allLines`'. But Method 2 doesn't need extra space. But will it do the split for '`n`' lines?

Which method is efficient?

Comment: There's no difference - Python is still creating a list internally to store the results of the `split()` - as far as I know, there is no method in the standard library to allow you to split a string without creating an intermediate list. You'd have to write your own function.

Comment: why would you need/use BeautifulSoup in order to iterate over lines of txt file? Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/6475407/4046632

Comment: @buran: Sorry to mention it. It is a general routine. Sometimes I may send an HTML file to the function.

Comment: Those two formulations are entirely equivalent.  You *can* use `StringIO` to do the line splitting and save the memory for the copies of each line, but then you *have* to keep the whole file-string around during processing, and I don’t know if it’s any faster.