# Determine if a file is "more likely" json or csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, mime

I have a few files with generalized extensions, such as "txt" or no extension at all. I'm trying to determine in a very quick manner whether the file is json or a csv. I thought of using the `magic` module, but it doesn't work for what I'm trying to do. For example:

```
>>> import magic
>>> magic.from_file('my_json_file.txt')
'ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators'
```

Is there a better way to determine if something is json or csv? I'm unable to load the entire file, and I want to determine it in a very quick manner. What would be a good solution here?

Comment: Even if there is a way to find out the _type_ of file based on its contents, you may not get accurate results if the JSON inside the file is invalid or if the delimiter is not consistent across the csv data and such other problems. Moreover, everything inside a txt file is considered as `string` type, doesn't matter if its JSON or not.

Comment: @amanb that's fine if it's not valid. I just want to see -- based on the first 1000 characters in the file is the "probably json or probably csv". Right now doing something like `s.startswith('{')` is giving me better results than `magic` so there's got to be something that's a bit more accurate...

Comment: Hmm, you are unable to load the entire file, but magic.from_file is able to say that there are no line terminators. Apparently it can load the entire file.

Comment: [Helpful semi-related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475328/how-can-i-read-large-text-files-in-python-line-by-line-without-loading-it-into) for future reference

Comment: @RemcoGerlich I've just copy-pasted some data into that file for testing purposes. The files could be very large (10GB) and I'm only downloading the first 1KB or so to see which file type it may be where it doesn't have an explicit extension.

Comment: `"hello"` is itself a valid standalone JSON document (for some versions of the standard). Which is to say that if you're looking at a degenerate (single-row, single-column) case, the same document can be *both* a valid CSV file and a valid JSON file. :)

Comment: Maybe it's as easy as checking whether there's a line break character in the first 1000 characters. Then it's a CSV. Will probably work for the vast majority of cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if the file starts with either `{` or `[` to determine if it's JSON, and you can load the first two lines with `csv.reader` and see if the two rows have the same number of columns to determine if it's CSV.

```
import csv
with open('file') as f:
    if f.read(1) in '{[':
        print('likely JSON')
    else:
        f.seek(0)
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        try:
            if len(next(reader)) == len(next(reader)) > 1:
                print('likely CSV')
        except StopIteration:
            pass
```

Comment: simple approach, I like this. Thanks for this solution.

Comment: one question on this -- why wouldn't you want to open the file in `rb` mode? What if, for example, it's not in utf-8 coding (let's say it's utf-16 encoding)?

Comment: It's not required for all rows to have the same number of columns in a CSV. Indeed, leaving a completely blank row after the header and before the beginning of data is not unheard of.

Comment: beautiful solution!..I may use it for my own purposes some day.

Comment: But if it's a 10GB JSON file on a single line, then this is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `try/catch` "technique" trying to parse the data to JSON object. When loading an invalid formatted JSON from a string it raises a `ValueError` which  you can catch and process however you want:

```py
>>> import json
>>> s1 = '{"test": 123, "a": [{"b": 32}]}'
>>> json.loads(s1)
```

If valid, nothing happens, if not:

```py
>>> import json
>>> s2 = '1;2;3;4'
>>> json.loads(s2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 2 - line 1 column 8 (char 1 - 7)
```

So you can build a function as follows:

```py
import json

def check_format(filedata):
    try:
        json.loads(filedata)
        return 'JSON'
    except ValueError:
        return 'CSV'

>>> check_format('{"test": 123, "a": [{"b": 32}]}')
'JSON'
>>> check_format('1;2;3;4')
'CSV'
```

Comment: For this you need to read the whole file though, and he can't.