# Fastest way to get line with sub string from a file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting

I have a list of files I want to extract a line containing a particular string from each of these files. What would be the fastest way to do this? 
Eg.

File:

```
fisrt line 
second line 
some gossip is innate
smush smush
squish bust
although
last line
```

I want the line containing `gossip` and therefore should get

```
some gossip is innate
```

in return.

I am looking for something that can emulate the performance of `grep` from a bash shell in python.

Comment: Did you try something? Was it not fast enough? Or what was the problem?

Comment: Use the `in` operator or a regular expression with word boundaries. The former will be faster while the latter more accurate.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I used the method to open a file, save all the lines using `readlines` and then searching for the line containing the string. The approach seemed rather inefficient to me and I am looking for a better one at the same

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475328/how-can-i-read-large-text-files-in-python-line-by-line-without-loading-it-into

Answer (score 0):

As for timing issues, make yourself comfortable with the [**`timeit` module.**](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/timeit.html)
For your specific problem, you have two choices, the `in` operator and a more accurate regex approach:

```
import re, timeit

content = """
fisrt line 
second line 
some gossip is innate
smush smush
squish bust
although
last line
"""

def only_string_functions():
    return [line for line in content.split("\n") if "gossip" in line]

pattern = re.compile(r'\bgossip\b')
def regex_approach():
    return [line for line in content.split("\n") if pattern.search(line)]

print(timeit.timeit(only_string_functions, number=10**5))
print(timeit.timeit(regex_approach, number=10**5))
```

Running this a 100.000 times, it yields on my `MacBook`:

```
0.11374067
0.40804803300000003
```

So, as expected, the `in` operator is by far faster (about three times) than the regex approach but will give you lines like `mygossip should not be matched` as well - this may or may not be a problem.

Comment: This approach stores the contents of the file in a variable and processes on them. As mentioned in the question, I am looking for an approach like `grep` from bash where I can save time on reading all of the file and then iterating through the lines in this list of lines.