# I want to replace odd lines if the value is present else if not present add it

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I have a sample text file having data like this

```
<iden/><provider></provider><trace>065110d4-cec5-d433772ed57a</trace>
<ServiceRQ>Some xml data</ServiceRQ>
<iden/><provider></provider>
<ServiceRQ>Some xml data</ServiceRQ>
```

like this and so on it is quite a large file.
I want to check the **odd line** if `<trace>065110d4-cec5-43f9-b089-d433772ed57a</trace>` is present that replace it with `<trace>xyz</trace>` else if `<trace>065110d4-cec5-43f9-b089-d433772ed57a</trace>` is not present then add `<trace>xyz</trace>`
my code:

```
with open("Sample_xml.txt", 'r') as fp:
    output = fp.readlines()
    type(output)
    s = len(output) - 1
    tc = 0
    rq = 1
    while (tc <= s) and (rq <= s):
        if tc % 2 == 0:
            a = (output[tc])
            if a.find("<trace") != -1:
                a = re.sub('(?<=<trace>)(.*?)(?=</trace>)','xyz', a)
                print(a)
            elif a.find("<trace>") == -1:
                a = a.rstrip() + '<trace>xyz</trace>' +'\n'
                print(a)
        if rq % 2 != 0:
            b = (output[rq])
            print(b)
        with open("Fin_xml.txt", "a") as myfile:
            myfile.write(a)
            myfile.write(b + '\n')
     
        tc += 2
        rq += 2
```

the file is so large greater that 800mb so this code is not working properly with readlines(). Please can someone help me with my code

Answer (score 0):

If I understand  correctly, you don't want to read entire file (But I don't think that 800mb is that much).
 In this case instead of `fp.readlines()` you can use `next(fp)` and read each line one by one. Do it twice if you want to skip line.
Also take a look - [read large files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475328/how-can-i-read-large-text-files-line-by-line-without-loading-it-into-memory)

Answer (score 0):

As @Archili Robakidze pointed out you could read a large file line by line. This will ensure only the one line is kept in memory.

Also you could simplify the code. Use `enumerate` to get the line number. Since you are starting with the very first line in the file as `line 1` instead of `line 0` use `enumerate(fp, 1)`:

```py
import re

with open("Sample_xml.txt", 'r') as fp:
    for i, line in enumerate(fp, 1):
        # If the line number is odd, do the check and replace
        if i%2 != 0:
            if line.find("<trace") != -1:
                line = re.sub('(?<=<trace>)(.*?)(?=</trace>)','xyz', line)
                print(line)
            elif line.find("<trace>") == -1:
                line = line.rstrip() + '<trace>xyz</trace>' +'\n'
                print(line)
        with open("Fin_xml.txt", "a") as myfile:
            myfile.write(line)
```