# Porting a sub-class of python2 'file' class to python3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, porting, python-2to3

I have a legacy code that calls `class TiffFile(file)`. What is the python3 way to call it?

I tried to replace following in python2:

```
class TiffFile(file):
    def __init__(self, path):
        file.__init__(self, path, 'r+b')
```

By this in python3:

```
class TiffFile(RawIOBase):
    def __init__(self, path):
        super(TiffFile, self).__init__(path, 'r+b')
```

But now I am getting `TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters`

Comment: How is this object used? You can probably make it a *function* instead, that just calls `open()`.

Comment: it is used to return an object with a bunch of attributes. it probably can work, but the whole code is OO

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`RawIOBase.__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase) does not take any arguments, that is where you error is.

Your `TiffFile` implementation also inherits [`file`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file) which is not a a class, but a constructor function, so your Python 2 implementation is non-idiomatic, and someone could even claim it is wrong-ish. You should use `open` instead of `file`, and in a class context you should use an `io` module class for input and output.

You can use [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) to return a file object for use as you would use `file` in Python 2.7 or you can use `io.FileIO` in both [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.FileIO) and [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.FileIO) for accessing file streams, like you would do with `open`.

So your implementation would be more like:

```
import io

class TiffFile(io.FileIO):
    def __init__(self, name, mode='r+b', *args, **kwargs):
        super(TiffFile, self).__init__(name, mode, *args, **kwargs)
```

This should work in all currently supported Python versions and allow you the same interface as your old implementation while being more correct and portable.

Are you actually using `r+b` for opening the file in read-write-binary mode on Windows? You should probably be using `rb` mode if you are not writing into the file, but just reading the TIFF data. `rb` would open the file in binary mode for reading only. The appended `+` sets the file to open in read-write mode.

Comment: I am not sure the meaning of 'r+b', it is an older piece of code I want to call from Python3. It does write back into the file it opens.

Comment: `r` mode opens file in read and `r+` opens it in read-write, `r+b` opens it in read-write-binary mode, so it reads and writes in binary. Binary mode is appropriate for image, video and music files, which don't have text encoded data. Usually it is best to open file once for reading it and then write new data into another file to avoid mutating the file while possibly reading it, which can create very hard-to-debug side-effects.

Comment: this package writes stuff back by design, as files are huge. i won't mess with it for now