# What Python module does the file() method belong to?

Tags: python

I am reading a blog post related to a [Recurrent Neural Network for Natural Language Processing](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/gist/yoavg/d76121dfde2618422139) and am trying to recreate the code to practice with. The sample code uses a method to read in a .txt file called `file().read()`. I am not familiar with this method and would like to know if it's contained in an importable module, or at least what it would return so I could recreate the method with with different code.

I did attempt to substitute a `with open(filename) as f` but it did not return the data in the same format as the `file().read()` method seems to. "File" isn't the easiest term to Google if you're looking for a specific result!

```
def train_char_lm(fname, order=4):
    data = file(fname).read()
    lm = defaultdict(Counter)
    pad = "~" * order
    data = pad + data
    for i in xrange(len(data)-order):
        history, char = data[i:i+order], data[i+order]
        lm[history][char]+=1
    def normalize(counter):
        s = float(sum(counter.values()))
        return [(c,cnt/s) for c,cnt in counter.iteritems()]
    outlm = {hist:normalize(chars) for hist, chars in lm.iteritems()}
    return outlm
```

Comment: `open(filename).read()` should work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47838405/porting-a-sub-class-of-python2-file-class-to-python3

Comment: I'd use `data = f.read()` with a `with open(filename) as f:` block as you suggested rather than the bare `open().read()`, might as well use the auto-close from the context manager. But otherwise, yeah, that's the Python 3+ replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Typing

```
help(file)
```

into the IDLE interpreter yields

```
Help on class file in module __builtin__:
```

plus additional useful info for you. It is part of the built-in module.