# Segmentation fault (core dumped) while trying to execute the stem file

Tags: c, file, io

I have a stem file named `myfile`, it has 2 sub files : `myfile.data` and `myfile.names`.

Now I want to write a code where it will first check the `.names` file's last line and see whether there is a zero or not, if there is any other number other than zero then it will say `noisy data`. And if the `.names` files last line has a zero, then I need to read the .data file and do some operations on that `.data` file to produce a valid output.

Now below I am giving what I have tried to do:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
                char* path;
                sprintf(path, "%s.names", argv[1]);
                printf("...%s...\n", path);
                //FILE *fp =stdin;
                fp = fopen(path, "r");
                
                char buff[1024];
                int check = 0;

                fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

                while(!feof(fp))
                {
                    memset(buff, 0x00, 1024);
                    fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]\n", buff);
                }
                
                if(strchr(buff, '0') != NULL){
                    check = 1;
                }
                
                if(check == 0){
                    printf("Noisy data...\n");
                }
                
                else if(check == 1){
                    
                    char* path1;
                    sprintf(path1, "%s.data", argv[1]);
                    printf("...%s...", path1);
                    //FILE *fp1 = stdin;
                    fp1 = fopen(path1, "r");
                    
                    char buf[1024];
                
                    if( fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp1) == NULL ){
                        fputs("Input error\n", stderr);
                        return 1;
                    }
                    ...
                    ...
                    Produces the perfect output
}
```

It is compiling successfully.

To execute this : `<./executable_filename> <stemFileName> > <outputFileName>`

So whenever I am doing : `./myFileName myfile output`. It is saying `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`. Why is it happening?

One more point my .names files will contain either : `| Final Pseudo Deletion Count is 0.` or `| Final Pseudo Deletion Count is 1.` or `| Final Pseudo Deletion Count is 2.` , So I guess the `strchr` will do my job is this case?

I initially tried to modify this below code, but after trying several different ways, I am not able to.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

FILE * xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode);
void * xmalloc(size_t s);

void parse_line(const char *buf, int *max, int column_count)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < column_count; i++ ){
        char *end;
        int t = strtol(buf, &end, 10);
        
        if( t > max[i] ){
            max[i] = t;
        }
        
        if( !((i < column_count - 1 && *end == ',') || (i == column_count - 1 && *end == '\n')) ){
            fprintf(stderr, "invalid input '%c' in %s", *end, buf);
            exit(1);
        }
        buf = end + 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    char *path1;
    char *path = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "stdin";
    
    sprintf(path, "%s.data", argv[1]);
    
    FILE *in = argc > 1 ? xfopen(path, "r") : stdin;
    
    char buf[1024];
    int column_count = 1;
    int row_count = 1;
    int *max;

    /* Read first line to determine number of columns */
    if( fgets(buf, sizeof buf, in) == NULL ){
        fputs("Input error\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    for( const char *p = buf; *p; p++ ){
        if( *p == ',' ){
            column_count += 1;
        }
    }
    
    max = xmalloc(column_count * sizeof *max);
    
    for( int i = 0; i < column_count; i++ ){
        max[i] = INT_MIN;
    }
    
    parse_line(buf, max, column_count);
    while( fgets(buf, sizeof buf, in) != NULL ){
        row_count += 1;
        parse_line(buf, max, column_count);
    }
    
    if( fseek(in, 0L, SEEK_SET) ){
        perror(path);
        return 1;
    }
    
    printf("%d %d ", row_count, column_count - 1);
    
    for( int i = 0; i < column_count - 1; i += 1 ){
        printf("%d ", max[i]);
    }
    
    printf("%d\n", max[column_count - 1] + 1);

    while( fgets(buf, sizeof buf, in) != NULL ){
        char *comma = strrchr(buf, ',');
        if( comma == NULL ){
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid input\n");
            return 1;
        }
        
        *comma = '\0';
        int k = strtol(comma + 1, NULL, 10);
        for(char *p = buf; *p;  p++){
            if( *p == ',' ) *p = ' '; 
        }
        printf("%s %d\n", buf, k + 1);
    }
}

FILE *
xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode)
{
    FILE *fp = path[0] != '-' || path[1] != '\0' ? fopen(path, mode) :
        *mode == 'r' ? stdin : stdout;
    if( fp == NULL ){
        perror(path);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    return fp;
}

void *
xmalloc(size_t s)
{
    void *rv = malloc(s);
    if( rv == NULL ){
        perror("malloc");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return rv;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several bugs here:

```
                char* path;
                sprintf(path, "%s.names", argv[1]);
```

The buffer passed to `sprintf` must point to writable memory, but `path` is uninitialized and doesn't point anywhere in particular. See [Crash or "segmentation fault" when data is copied/scanned/read to an uninitialized pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37549594/crash-or-segmentation-fault-when-data-is-copied-scanned-read-to-an-uninitializ). You probably want `path` to be an array instead of a pointer.

Your compiler can warn you about many bugs like this, if you enable warnings, e.g. with `gcc -Wall -O`.  [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings/)

Also, since you cannot control the length of the string `argv[1]`, no fixed length of the buffer can ever be long enough, so you probably want to use `snprintf` instead to prevent a buffer overflow.  See [understanding the dangers of sprintf(...)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3662899/understanding-the-dangers-of-sprintf) (which is for C++ but addresses the same issue).

You have the same problems for `path1` further down.

```
fp = fopen(path, "r");
```

`fopen` will return NULL if it fails, and your code doesn't check for this.  Your program would segfault in that case.  Same problem with `fp1` further down.

```
while(!feof(fp))
```

This is [always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

```
fscanf(fp, "%[^\n]\n", buff);
```

A similar overflow risk as with `sprintf`.  Also, you must check `fscanf` for success; that is the proper way to check for end-of-file, in place of your erroneous `while (!feof(fp))`.

```
if( fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp1) == NULL ){
                        fputs("Input error\n", stderr);
                        return 1;
```

`fgets` returning NULL does not necessarily indicate an "input error"; it could be simply that the end of the file has been reached.

---

For general information on causes of segmentation faults and how to debug them, see also

- [What is a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346806/what-is-a-segmentation-fault)
- [Definitive List of Common Reasons for Segmentation Faults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047452/definitive-list-of-common-reasons-for-segmentation-faults)
- [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Thank you so much for this help. But I am trying to correct and rectify the code but I am unable to, as I am very new to C. If I give the initial code, which I tried to modify, can you please help me out! I just want to modify the code where it will first check the `.names` file's last line and see whether there is a zero or not, if there is any other number other than `zero` then it will say `noisy data`. And if the `.names` files last line has a zero, then I need to read the `.data` file and do some operations on that .data file to produce a `valid output.` I am posting my code below.

Comment: @Dev: There isn't a simple way to read just the last line of a file, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29884493/how-can-i-read-lines-from-bottom-up-using-c/29884555#29884555.  You normally just have to read the whole thing, and figure out in retrospect which line was last.