# seek() not working properly, although file opened in "r" mode

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, file-io, seek

I have a CSV file of dates and a float (day,month,year,float). here is sample,

```
1,1,2000,4076.79
2,1,2000,1216.82
3,1,2000,1299.68
4,1,2000,637.36
5,1,2000,3877.91
6,1,2000,3308.99
7,1,2000,2925.93
8,1,2000,1559.09
9,1,2000,3190.81
10,1,2000,3008.66
11,1,2000,2026.35
12,1,2000,3279.61
13,1,2000,3601.6
14,1,2000,2021.1
15,1,2000,2103.62
16,1,2000,609.64
17,1,2000,633.16
18,1,2000,1195.34
```

I want to read the first line then the last one:

```
handle = open(getInputFileName(), "r")
```

getInputFileName() obv. is a function that return file name. then,

```
print "numberlines", numberLines        #DEBUG# 
>>> 3660
```

numberLines is the number of lines in file. then,

```
handle.seek(0)
lineData = handle.readline().split(",")
print lineData      #DEBUG#
>>> ['1','1','2000','4076.79\n']
```

until here everything works just fine. but then,

```
handle.seek(numberLines-1)
lineData = handle.readline().split(",")
print lineData      #DEBUG#
>>>['7', '7', '2000', '2347.51\n']
```

but in fact the last line in file is `31,12,2009,3823.02`
why isnt seek going all the way down?
i tried deleting the line that it gets stuck at but then the program crashed `ValueError: could not convert string to float:` (I then use lineData as float):

```
newestDate.insert(1,float(lineData[1]))
```

I checked the file if there was a problem with lines but the format never changes. how come does my code work for the first line but not the last?

Comment: seek seeks to a file position in bytes. NOT linenumber. Read the doku: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=seek#file.seek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[file.seek(offset[, whence])](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=seek#file.seek) operates on byte-positions inside the file. Not linenumbers. If you want to operate on lines, use readline() or iterate the file:

```
with ("file.txt", "r") as f:
    first = next(f) # see comment Jean-François Fabre
    for last in f:  # and tdelanys comment :o)
        pass # do nothing with all other lines, last will hold the last one
```

now `first` and `last` hold the first and last line respectively.

The advantage here is that you hold 1 line of text at max in memory and discard the rest. AFAIK there is no way to simply get 1st and last line of a file without stepping through it.

If you want to parse the data though, follow [DyZ suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50456953/7505395) of using the csv module and a reader - its safer. If you feel adventourous - go for [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) , it has plenty of buildin csv capability :) and is able to read big csv's chunkwise to be more memory friendly (see f.e. [How to read a 6 GB csv file with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-to-read-a-6-gb-csv-file-with-pandas) )

Comment: `first = next(f)` to get the first line is smarter

Comment: `for last in f: pass` should do.

Comment: you can get the last line, but you need to seek to the end, and seek back char by char until you find either position 0 or a linefeed. Maybe interesting if the file is very big: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167008/efficiently-finding-the-last-line-in-a-text-file

Answer (score 3):

Do not read CSV files by hand (your code fails if there is any quoted item with a comma in a row, like `...,"1,2000",...`). There is a CSV reader for that:

```
import csv
with open("foo.csv") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    data = list(reader)

data[0] # First
# ['1', '1', '2000', '4076.79']
data[-1] # Last
#['18', '1', '2000', '1195.34']
```

If memory is an issue, read the first line, skip the rest of the file, and retain the last line, as explained in the other answer.

Comment: you can apply Patrick code on `reader` so you don't have to load all the data

Comment: I think this is faster... if you can afford the memory :)