# How to read last string in a file

Tags: python

I have a file.txt which is saving as list

`['Joe', '101', '/home/Joe', '43242', '/home/Joe/1.txt']`

How to read the last element in the file here it is `'/home/Joe/1.txt'`

I tried to read

```
with open ('file.txt', r) as fr:
   fd = fr.readlines()
   print (fd[-1])
```

Comment: What are you getting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Efficiently finding the last line in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167008/efficiently-finding-the-last-line-in-a-text-file)

Comment: I would suggest you to use pickle.. to store and retrieve the list directly..

Comment: Does the file contain exactly the only line you typed?

Comment: So the txt file contains a list?

Comment: @AvishkaDambawinna,  yes only one line

Comment: @Aaron yes its a list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [**`ast.literal_eval()`**](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval)

```
from ast import literal_eval

with open("test.txt") as fp:
    content = fp.read()
    lst = literal_eval(content)
    print(lst[-1])
    # /home/Joe/1.txt
```

As said in the commentary, better use other structures to store your information, e.g. `pickle`, `json`, etc.

Comment: can you share some insights or links?

Comment: @user1875458: What kind of insights are you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Please change ***t to 'rt'*** when reading from a file in python:

```
with open ('file.txt', 'rt') as fr:
  fd = fr.readlines()
  print (fd[-1])
```

Note: it is ***'rt'*** instead of ***t***.

Answer (score 0):

Try to,

```
 with open('file.txt') as fr:
     fd = fr.readlines()[0].split(',')[-1].strip(']')
     print(fd)

 #'/home/Joe/1.txt'
```