# I'm tailing a file in python for any changes and it is not picking up a change to the file

Tags: python, file, readline, tail

Here is my script:

```
def tail(file, delay=0.5):
    f = open(file, 'r')
    f.seek(0, 2)
    while True:    
        line = f.readline()
        print 'line: ' + line
        if not line:
            time.sleep(delay)
        else:
            print 'line found!'
```

When i open the file and add some lines to it, this script is not picking it up.  I am doing this on linux.

Comment: Your example code works for me. How are you writing to the file?

Comment: i am opening it in vi and adding some lines to it and then writing it.

Comment: That's odd... I did the same thing and it still works for me. I'm not sure what to tell you. (For testing the Python code itself, I would use `echo linetexthere >> file` instead of an editor like vi)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/182197/how-do-i-watch-a-file-for-changes-using-python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136168/get-last-n-lines-of-a-file-with-python-similar-to-tail

Comment: David, thanks for input, the problem was adding a line to the file with vi.  That did not work, however appending some text via echo did work.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

use `open('filename', 'a')` instead of `open('filename', 'r')` for adding lines to the file ... I think you actually want to append to the file rather than reading it.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine so there is likely a buffering issue.  Try using f.read(100) instead of readline so that you read whatever is available rather than searching for line endings.

Comment: I did that and still do not get anything.  Is this because the file is buffered in memory so it won't detect changes on disk?