# Read new line with pynotify

Tags: python, file, events, pynotify

I'm trying to display a new line that was added to the file.
So imagine that I have a `sample_file.txt` :

```
 1. line 1
 2. line 2
 3. line 3
```

I want to check if this file got a new line, and than display that line (without printing all the file again)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import pyinotify
from datetime import datetime
import time

PATH = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~/'), 'sample_file.txt')

m = pyinotify.WatchManager()
m.add_watch(PATH, pyinotify.ALL_EVENTS, rec=True)
notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(m, pyinotify.ProcessEvent(), 0,  0, 100)

f = open(PATH)
for line in f.readlines():
    print line

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    try:
        if notifier.check_events():
            # RIGHT HERE:
            # HOW TO DO SOMETHING LIKE
            # f.last() ???
            print f.next()
        else:
            print 'waiting for a line....'
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        notifier.stop()
        break
```

What I was thinking is to read all the lines somewhere before while loop, and than print the next line, but something wrong in my code, and it checks for `f.next()` right after it comes to the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll address the two issues:

- how to implement `tail` on a file,
- and how to use the `pyinotify` module.

## Tail on a file

In your code, you need to:

- try and read as much full lines as you can using `read` or `readlines`,
- rewind the file to the start of the last incomplete line until you can print it using `seek`.

This translates for example into:

```
f = open(PATH)
for line in f.readlines():
    print line[:-1]

while True:
    time.sleep(5)
    try:
        line_start = f.tell()
        new_lines = f.read()
        last_n = new_lines.rfind('\n')
        if last_n >= 0:
            # We got at least one full line
            line_start += last_n + 1
            print new_lines[:last_n]
        else:
            # No complete line yet
            print 'no line'
        f.seek(line_start)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        notifier.stop()
        break
```

You can find more examples here, although some do not address additions to the file which do not end with a newline:

- https://github.com/kasun/python-tail/blob/master/tail.py
- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/157035-tail-f-in-python/

And some alternatives here [How can I tail a log file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523044/how-can-i-tail-a-log-file-in-python)

## Pyinotify loop

You should also move your code inside `pyinotify`'s event handlers as explained in the documentation.

`check_events` returns `True` if there are events to be processed, but it does not actually process the events, so by itself it will always return `True` until events have been processed.

Also, try and avoid `while`/`sleep` loops. Inotify adds the capability to handle an event as soons as it is received, without compromising resources. A `while`/`sleep` loop will be less reactive.

Below are the two first methods form the [Short Tutorial](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki/Tutorial#short-tutorial) on `pyinotify`.

### 1. Monitoring endlessly

This is the preferred method if you have no other event loop, as it will be the most reactive:

```
PATH = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~/'), 'experiments', 'testfile')

class EventHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EventHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.file = open(PATH)
        self.position = 0
        self.print_lines()

    def process_IN_MODIFY(self, event):
        print 'event received'
        self.print_lines()

    def print_lines(self):
        new_lines = self.file.read()
        last_n = new_lines.rfind('\n')
        if last_n >= 0:
            self.position += last_n + 1
            print new_lines[:last_n]
        else:
            print 'no line'
        self.file.seek(self.position)

wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
handler = EventHandler()
notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, handler)
wm.add_watch(PATH, pyinotify.IN_MODIFY, rec=True)
notifier.loop()
```

### 2. Monitoring periodically

If you already have a processing loop, then it's just a matter of calling `process_events` periodically. The `EventHandler` class is the same as in method 1, but now instead of calling `notifier.loop()` we add a small timeout to the notifier, and implement our own event loop.

```
...

wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
handler = EventHandler()
notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, handler, timeout=10)
wm.add_watch(PATH, pyinotify.IN_MODIFY, rec=True)

while True:
    # Do something unrelated to pyinotify
    time.sleep(5)

    notifier.process_events()
    #loop in case more events appear while we are processing
    while notifier.check_events():
        notifier.read_events()
        notifier.process_events()
```

Comment: I am wondering how to prevent `new_lines = self.file.read()`. The `read()` seems quite expensive because each time the file is edited, you have to read the entire file which is not wise.

Comment: @zizheng-wu `self.file.read()` will read from the current file descriptor position, set by `self.file.seek(self.position)`. Because we only seek back to the position just after the last seen '\n', this will only read the new lines, not the entire file. In the (rare) event that data is written without a terminating '\n' to the file, some reads could be further avoided by storing the read data instead of seeking back to the last '\n'.