# How can I detect special word occurs in teraterm log in run time using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I use teraterm as my client-console and save the console log somewhere.

When I open the teraterm and do something on my COM1 serial port (attached with a device),
it will print messages on the screen and write to the log file simultaneously,

if I want to watch the log , to detect if any special word occurs  .

I thought if I use the "open" method , I can only get the whole content at the opened time , but can not get the latest content  the teraterm write after the opened time?

How could I achieve this?
Thank you all in advance~

Comment: Duplicate: [How can I tail a log file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523044/how-can-i-tail-a-log-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

Periodically check file size:

```
import os
import time

log_path = '/tmp/com1.log'
special_word = 'magic'

lastsize = 0
while 1:
    if os.path.exists(log_path) and os.path.getsize(log_path) > lastsize:
        with open(log_path) as f:
            f.seek(lastsize)
            for line in f:
                if special_word in line:
                    print('Special word found')
            lastsize = f.tell()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use teraterm's [macro langauge](http://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/macro/), it allows the developers to extend the behaviour of teraterm.

For your specific case, teraterm's macro language provides [wait family](http://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/macro/command/wait.html) of functions to wait for a particular sequence of word (or) pattern. Mind that teraterm macro language is not python, but it has its own syntax.

```
; wait for special world 'hello'
wait 'hello'
if result == 0 goto your_own_logic
```

There are other ways if you want to have a python only solution. Instead of using teraterm to connect with serial port, you could use [pyserial](http://pyserial.sourceforge.net/pyserial_api.html) python library to connect with serial port.