# Tail file graphically with PyQt

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt

I'm trying to do what sounds fairly simple but I keep running in to all sorts of problems.
I'm trying to create a GUI that can tail several files at the same time using PyQt.
I saw this answer on how to tail a file in pure Python

[How can I tail a log file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523044/how-can-i-tail-a-log-file-in-python)

I have tried using this code inside of a QThread.
The issues I'm having here are that the tail process never stops by itself; it needs to be killed.
It should be killed when the GUI is closed.
The other issues I'm getting with this specific solution below is

```
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
```

and

```
QWaitCondition::wakeAll(): mutex lock failure:
```

and

```
QThread: Destroyed while thread is still running
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tailer.py", line 27, in run
    self.emit(SIGNAL('newline'), line.rstrip())
RuntimeError: underlying C/C++ object has been deleted
```

Other implementations I've tried have had the tail process complaining about a broken pipe but those stopped appearing once I did stderr=PIPE as well.
I'm worried now that I could be missing errors since I never read from stderr (since it would block and there shouldn't be any output).

To get the errors fire this up trying to tail 3 different file.
I wrote another script that loops and writes to those 3 files doing a sleep of 0.1 seconds.
I close the GUI and start it up over and over again.  Sometimes I get errors sometimes I don't.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

import os
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

class Tailer(QThread):

    def __init__(self, fname, parent=None):
        super(Tailer, self).__init__(parent)
        self.fname = fname
        self.connect(self, SIGNAL('finished()'), self.cleanup)

    def cleanup(self):
        print 'CLEANING UP'
        self.p.kill()
        print 'killed'

    def run(self):
        command = ["tail", "-f", self.fname]
        print command
        self.p = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
        while True:
            line = self.p.stdout.readline()
            self.emit(SIGNAL('newline'), line.rstrip())
            if not line:
                print 'BREAKING'
                break

    def foo(self):
        self.p.kill()

class TailWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, fnames, parent=None):
        super(TailWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.threads = {}
        self.browsers = {}
        for i, fname in enumerate(fnames):
            if not os.path.exists(fname):
                print fname, "doesn't exist; creating"
                p = Popen(['touch', fname], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
                out, err = p.communicate()
                ret = p.wait()
                assert ret == 0
            t = Tailer(fname, self)
            self.threads[fname] = t
            b = QTextBrowser()
            self.browsers[fname] = b
            layout.addWidget(QLabel('Tail on %s' % fname), 0, i)
            layout.addWidget(b, 1, i)
            self.connect(t, SIGNAL("newline"), b.append)
            t.start()
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        for fname, t in self.threads.items():
            t.foo()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tw = TailWidget(sys.argv[1:])
    tw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the main thread isn't waiting on the background threads.

You tell them to stop here:

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    for fname, t in self.threads.items():
        t.foo()
```

So, this kills all of the subprocesses, which will make all of the background threads quit *eventually*. But it won't make them stop *immediately*. That won't happen until the next time each one gets to its `readline`.

After killing the subprocesses, you return, letting Qt immediately close your window and destroy your widget. Any background threads that try to send a signal to that widget will then fail.

Imagine that thread 1 has done a `readline`, and is in the middle of its `rstrip` when thread 0 tries to close down. So, thread 0 kills thread 1's subprocess, then deletes the main widget. Thread 1 finishes its `rstrip` and calls `emit`, and it's now sending to a deleted widget.

Comment: What do you recommend as a solution?

Comment: A quick&dirty solution is to block until the threads go away in `closeEvent`, but that's ugly (and could, in theory, block the UI thread long enough to cause beachballing). Alternatively, to use `deleteLater` to sequence your deletes. Or you can swallow `close` and add another signal (or similarly let the `close` happen, but hold off on destroying the object by not going right to `quit`). Or do the `newline` signal indirectly (e.g., via a signal to another object, or a `weakref`) so it's safe even after the main thread has died. Or use `moveToThread` instead of overriding `QThread.run`.

Comment: But on looking at your code again… it may actually be something even more basic. Can you add `__del__` methods that print something to both `Tailer` and `TailWidget` and show the sequence when it does and doesn't crash? Because it's possible that it's only crashing because the `Tailer` is deleted, not the `TailWidget`, in which case just keeping the `Tailer`s alive longer would solve the problem.