# Read CSV File in Django and then write it to DB Postgresql

Tags: django, csv, import, crud, django-postgresql

How can I read a CSV file, parse the values, and then output it to a particular database table?

That's the basic problem.

Here is a 'bigger picture' of what I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to either read from multiple CSV files (every minute) and or read from an ever-updating CSV file (with additional row entries every update) every minute.

Comment: therefore, i'm also gonna need to write to a db table every time i receive csvfile or everytime the csv file is updated

Comment: Welcome to SO!  If there is any information that you feel you left out of your question, there is a very convenient "edit" option.  You will find the button labeled "edit" underneath your question.  This allows you to add any pertinent information you feel you missed the first time around.  If information is not included in the question, people may skip over it when giving their answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523044/how-can-i-tail-a-log-file-in-python this question has answers on how to read a file every time a new line is written into it...