# python: reading file which is changing

Tags: python

I need to write a simple script which will display in real time the contents of `/proc/net/xt_recent/PORTSCAN`. This file is constantly changing and I want to read it in an infinite loop and display as accurately as possible the "instantaneous" state. A sample contents of my file looks like this:

```
src=123.45.67.89 ttl: 64 last_seen: 4298265432 oldest_pkt: 1 4298265432
src=132.45.67.89 ttl: 64 last_seen: 4298265432 oldest_pkt: 1 4298265432
src=231.45.67.89 ttl: 64 last_seen: 4298265432 oldest_pkt: 1 4298265432
```

Can I use the standard

```
line = f.readline()
```

Or is there some better way in to read this file. My concern is to avoid any possible inconsistencies, while reading a file which is changing (lines being added, removed, etc)

Comment: I suggest you to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523044/how-can-i-tail-a-log-file-in-python since the problem seems to be very similar

Comment: Do you want to do something with the lines or do you just want to display them? What os are you on?

Comment: yes, I will need to process the lines. My OS is Debian, in case it is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David Beazley had a great talk on [Generator Tricks for Systems Programmers](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/).

In particular, check out *Processing Infinite Data* section.  You can use his code to follow a file in real-time like `tail -f` in Unix.

Answer (score 1):

Great thing about python, is the numerous packages available from people "who had the same problem as you".

For "watching" files and acting on changes, see: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog/0.7.0

For a more general "shell" wrapper solution, see: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plumbum
The latter allows you to do `from plumbum.cmd import tail` and then just run `tail['/proc/net/xt_recent/PORTSCAN', '-1']` inside your loop as if you are in the shell.