# Forward new log messages via snmptrap

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, net-snmp

I try listen new file lines and resend it in `snmptraps`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

sreader = "tail -f /root/zsv/log"
ssreader = subprocess.Popen(sreader,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

strap = 'snmptrap -c iptvinfo -v 2c 192.168.10.10:163 "" 1.3.3.3.3.3.3.3 1.2.2.2.2.2.2 s '
subprocess.Popen([strap + ssreader.communicate()[0]],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

And I'm not getting anything..
This is my first program, please help fix it

Comment: Could you provide a series of shell commands that *works for you in a terminal* that you would like to translate to Python?

Comment: of course..
    tail -f "file-name"  
The -f option causes to not stop when end of file is reached, but rather to wait for additional data to be appended to the input. 

And example command to send snmp trap: 
    snmptrap -c iptvinfo -v 2c 10.144.216.91:163 "" 1.3.3.3.3.3.3.3 1.2.2.2.2.2.2 s same_text_from_tail

Comment: please, [edit] your question instead of posting in a comment (it enables formatting and more visible for other users)

Comment: Does `tail -f /root/zsv/log | snmptrap -c iptvinfo -v 2c 10.144.216.91:163 "" 1.3.3.3.3.3.3.3 1.2.2.2.2.2.2 s -` work?

Comment: No, I tried. it would be great

Comment: what does `snmptrap` accept as the argument a filename or a string to send? btw, you haven't provided a series of shell commands that work: I see no connection between `tail -f file-name` and `snmptrap ... same_text_from_tail` What is `same_text_from_tail`?

Comment: I want get new lines in file and forward it in snmp trap.
I tried read new strings in file with `tail -f <filename>`
and  tried sent  to snmp trap with `snmptrap -c iptvinfo -v 2c 10.144.216.91:163 "" 1.3.3.3.3.3.3.3 1.2.2.2.2.2.2 s <string to send in trap>`

Comment: does it work if you execute the commands manually in the shell?

Answer (score 0):

```
import shlex
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, check_call

snmptrap = shlex.split('snmptrap -c iptvinfo -v 2c 192.168.10.10:163 "" '
                       '1.3.3.3.3.3.3.3 1.2.2.2.2.2.2 s')
tail = Popen(["tail", "-f", filename], stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)
for line in iter(tail.stdout.readline, b''):
    check_call(snmptrap + [line]) # send line
tail.stdout.close()
rc = tail.wait()
```

Note: `shell=False` by default, `stderr` is not redirected.

You could change the code to send all available lines at once, or send only once a minute.

Depending on your needs, you could choose appropriate for your case `tail -f` implementation in Python. See [How can I tail a log file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12523044/4279) and 
[Get last n lines of a file with Python, similar to tail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/136168/4279).