# File following program

Tags: python, linux, tail

I am trying to build a python program that follows a log file checks for certain patterns. (Much like grep ..)

Part of the testing code 'test.py' is to read the stdin,

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    print line
```

so if I do this in one terminal

```
tail -f log.txt | python test.py
```

In another terminal

```
echo "hello" >> log.txt
```

you expect hello is print out on the first terminal, but it doesn't. How to change the code? I also want to use it like this

```
cat log.txt | python test.py
```

with the same test.py.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523044/how-can-i-tail-a-log-file-in-python) might help.

Comment: Thanks, but the post you point to seems only about tail -f, I actually want something a bit more general.

Comment: In the case of `tail -f log.txt | python test.py`, you do not see the output right away because of buffering. In the case of cat, the current contents of the file will get piped to the script. Script will exits once it see an end of file. So, if you write to the file afterwards, you script has already exited.

Comment: Did you try with `python -u test.py`?

Comment: add -u flag doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Echoing `sys.stdin` directly seems to work on my Mac OS laptop:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line.rstrip()
```

But interestingly, this didn't work very well on my Linux box. It would print the output from `tail -f` eventually, but the buffering was definitely making it appear as though the program was not working (it would print out fairly large chunks after several seconds of waiting).

Instead I got more responsive behavior by reading from `sys.stdin` one byte at a time:

```
import sys

buf = ''
while True:
    buf += sys.stdin.read(1)
    if buf.endswith('\n'):
        print buf[:-1]
        buf = ''
```

Comment: Interesting! I was on a mac when it was working, but now I'm on an Ubuntu machine and it's not working (either with or without the `-u` flag).