# Get return value from shell command in python

Tags: python, shell, unix

I'm doing `os.system` to tail for a live file and `grep` for a string 
How can I execute something when the grep succeeds? 
For example

```
cmd=  os.system(tail -f file.log | grep -i abc)
if (cmd):     
         #Do something and continue tail
```

Is there any way I can do this? It will only come to the `if` block when the os.system statement is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `subprocess.Popen` and read lines from stdout:

```
import subprocess

def tail(filename):
    process = subprocess.Popen(['tail', '-F', filename], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    while True:
        line = process.stdout.readline()

        if not line:
            process.terminate()
            return

        yield line
```

For example:

```
for line in tail('test.log'):
    if line.startswith('error'):
        print('Error:', line)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I am not sure that you really need to do this in python - perhaps it would e easier to pipe the `tail-f` output into awk: https://superuser.com/questions/742238/piping-tail-f-into-awk
2. If you want to work in python (because you need to do some processing afterwards) then check this link on how to use `tail -f`: [How can I tail a log file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523044/how-can-i-tail-a-log-file-in-python)