# Get Variable value from .sh to Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have an .sh file that produces a picture on Raspberry Pi. and inside this file I have the following:

Config.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
suffix=$(date +%H%M%S)  
cd /home/pi/photobooth_images/  
sudo cp image1.jpg /usb/photobooth_images/image-${suffix}-1.jpg  
sudo convert -size 1800x1200 xc:white \  
        image1.jpg -geometry 1536x1152+240+24 -composite \   
    /home/pi/template/logo.png -geometry 192x1152+24+24 -composite \  
        PB_${suffix}.jpg  
sudo cp PB_${suffix}.jpg /usb/photobooth_montage/PB_${suffix}.jpg  
sudo rm /home/pi/photobooth_images/*  
returnvalue=PB_${suffix}.jpg  
echo "$returnvalue"
```

What I am trying to do here is get the `PB_${suffix}.jpg` "returnvalue"  value (file name) it generated into Python. Now my Python program has this line, it runs the .sh file above.

Main.py:

```
return_value = subprocess.call("sudo ./" + config.sh, shell=True)  
print "The Value is: " + str(return_value) + " This value from Python"  

The output I get is this  
[08:33:02 04-10-2016] [PHOTO] Assembling pictures according to 1a template.  
PB_083302.jpg  
The Value is: 0 This value from Python  
The output I am expected should be something like "PB_070638.jpg"
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you shouldn't use `sudo` for simple operations like this. sudo is reserved for running administrative commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because `subprocess.call` only returns the return code of executing the script ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)). You want the actual output of what your script returns, so you should be using [check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output), and avoid using `shell=True`

```
subprocess.check_output(["sudo", "./", config.sh])
```

You also might want to revise running your script without root permission via `sudo`. It does not seem like something that *should* run using root privileges.

Comment: subprocess.check_output solved the issue,  thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Popen constructor the with stdout arg:

```
subprocess.Popen(['"sudo ./" + config.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

See also:
[Get return value from shell command in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135956/get-return-value-from-shell-command-in-python)

Also, here's more info on Popen in the Python docs.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor