# How can I get the last occurence of a text in a file that is automatically updated - python?

Tags: python

**[PROBLEM]**

In a File that refreshes automatically with new data, I want to get:
- the number that corresponds to latest string occcurence.
For instance, in the dummy example below above I want to fetch: 
- last occurence of **stringZ** and afterwards the number inside that text. **In practical terms I want to fetch: [99]**

```
File sample:    
    "....
    Manually launch test 1 stringX
    Manually launch test 2 stringY
    Manually launch test 3 stringW
    Manually launch test 10 stringZ
    ................
    Manually launch test 200 stringX
    Manually launch test 300 stringY
    Manually launch test 77 stringW
    Manually launch test 99 stringZ
    "
```

**[CODE]**

```
tempFile = open(fileName, "r")
while True:
    fileContent = str(tempFile.readlines())
    print temp
    latestOccurence= re.search("(.*)stringZ",fileContent ).group(0)
    latestOccurence= re.search('([0-9])+',latestOccurence).group(0)
    print latestOccurence
```

Comment: Do you mean how do I get the latest line written to a file as it updates? Also how are you watching the file?

Comment: @Padraic: I think he means last line containing `stringZ`.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus, that could be it  although looking at  `str(tempFile.readlines())` anything is possible

Comment: In the example above. I have : [Manually launch test 10 stringZ] and after some lines I have [Manually launch test 99 stringZ]. I want to get : a) latest occurence of the line where: stringZ is(in this case: Manually launch test 99 stringZ) +  b) latest number from that line (in this case: 99)

Comment: @Padraic. yes ;  last line containing stringZ. and from that line I will fetch the number (in my case 99)

Comment: @user3438538, this is very simple, loop over the lines keeping track of each time you find `stringZ` and the last line that has your substring will be the line you want

Comment: @user3438538, are you using a while loop to look for changes in the file?

Comment: yes. I use a while with time.sleep(1).

Comment: But how do you check later if you open the file outside the loop?  You should really use watchdog https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog

Comment: I think it is duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523044/how-can-i-tail-a-log-file-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
regex = re.compile(r'Manually launch test ([0-9]+) stringZ')
while True:
    latestOccurrence = None
    with open(fileName) as tempFile:
        for line in tempFile:
            if "stringZ" in line:
                match = regex.match(line)
                if match:
                    latestOccurrence = int(match.group(1))
    # do something with latestOccurrence here?
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I think it is not solving the problem that the file can be updated

Comment: @ wildwilhelm. thanks for suggestion, in the same time it fetches both occurences, namely: 10 and 99. I will keep investigating......

Comment: @user3438538 the code will match all occurrences in the file, but by the time the file is closed (i.e., where the comment "do something ..." is), the variable `latestOccurrence` should contain the last value found.