# Read only the updated part of a csv file in Python

Tags: python, json, csv

I have a csv file in which I append new results every 10 seconds. Every so (specified from a user) I read this csv and make a JSON file. I don't want to convert the whole csv into a JSON every time but only the last part that has been updated. So, I imagine that I will keep the last line every time, then I will start reading the file from this line and then to convert it to a JSON format.

```
myJson = {}
try:
    with open('myFile.csv', 'r') as f: #Read the csv file with read privileges.
            for line in f:
                lst = re.split(r' +', line.rstrip('\t')) #Columns are seperated with tabs.
                if len(lst) == 3: #There are three columns in the file:
                    n = lst[0].strip() #Names 
                    v = lst[1].strip() #Values 
                    p = lst[2].strip() #Percentages 
                    try:
                        myJson[n].append(v) #Add values to the according keys.
                    except KeyError:
                            myJson[n] = [v] #Handle potential KeyErrors.
except IOError:
    print "csv file has not been created yet."
```

The simplest way is to delete the csv file each time but it would be much more useful for me to keep it and just create new JSON files.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523044/how-can-i-tail-a-log-file-in-python

Comment: Maybe you should consider replacing that csv file with an actual database.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use another protocol to get your data shuffled from your producer to your consumer, for example a socket or a pipe. The approach pointed to by Lutz also works of course, but it relies on using a tool provided by the OS (tail).