# In Python can I read data from a text file which is getting appended dynamically

Tags: python

Consider the following Python script :

```
import time

f = open('data.txt')
while True :
    line = next(f)
    if line : print(line)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Now assume that when this code starts executing, `data.txt` contains only 5 physical lines. But this file `data.txt` is getting appended with more lines dynamically.

Is there some way that I can read the new lines that are getting appended to `data.txt`.

My observation is that the text read is the text existing in `data.txt` at the time `open` is performed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523044/how-can-i-tail-a-log-file-in-python#12523371

Comment: Check out `seek` method: https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/file/seek.html

Comment: seek method will not work unless you close the file handle and open it again.

Comment: @ lllrnr101 is it that when a file is opened a copy of this file is created for the reader process?

Comment: @Illmr101 Not sure why one would have to close the file handle. Just tried using opening a file in "a+" mode and using seek, write, and read together and it seems to work fine. Although I am not sure about mixing it with print rather than write.

Comment: @user3282758 Whether a copy is created or not depends on your OS, although most modern OS use some form of caching to improve read/write performance.

Comment: @Andrew Allaire if the same process opens in a+ mode and does read and write with a proper flush, it works. But I am talking about one process reading and the other parallelly modifying (say getting modified by an editor). In this case it does not work