# How to follow a large file in python without loading it all in the memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried the solution in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523044/how-can-i-tail-a-log-file-in-python), since the file I'm tailing can grow large than 50GB, the server is choking. Any suggestions on how to follow it without storing all in memory?

Comment: Which solution? None were accepted. Show your code

Comment: load file in chunck ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an external app.

```
import time
fsl = open('/var/syslog')
# Seek to end
fsl.seek(0,2)
last = fsl.tell()
# Back up 200 bytes
fsl.seek( last-200 )
while True:
    print( fsl.read() )
    time.sleep(5)
```

Now, this will print an extra linefeed every time it tries to get more data, but you can fix that.