# python readline function not reading the continuously updated log file properly

Tags: python, logging, readline

I have a python script which is reading a continuously updated log file line by line. During some instances the function is reading a single line as three lines.

Below is the function which is reading the log file continuously.

```
def follow(thefile):
    print("stilllll")
    thefile.seek(0, 2)
    while True:
        #time.sleep(0.1)
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line
```

Below code is for calling this function from main.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logfile = codecs.open("log.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8',errors='ignore')
    loglines = follow(logfile)
    for line in loglines:
```

Below is how logging is happening and log.txt is the file which is being written and read.

```
cat my1.fifo | telnet 172.27.172.247 10031 &> log.txt &
```

The below is the screenshot of line which was read as three lines.

[image]

It read it as three lines like this

```
0.0
[sudo] password
0.1643835616438356
for olta
0.09230769230769231
usr:
0.06451612903225806
```

What could be the reason for it ?

I tried to change the way it is reading the log file but since it is happening only some times then it is difficult to reproduce.

Comment: It looks like race condition, you read the line while being written in separate thread/process, while the thread in which you read is sleeping

Comment: If you want to have both file handler and console handler, why not setup logging with 2 handlers? i.e. this looks like XY problem to me

Comment: How can we prevent it from happening ? The log is written by a telnet process .

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12523044/4046632

Comment: The problem is the write is happening from somewhere else and it is not like both read and write are happening from the same code. So the above link did not help.

Comment: The main takeaway from the question I linked - don't yield until `line` ends with `'\n'`

Comment: yeah that can work but needs to be checked