# "\x00.......\x00" Output from file, not showing data

Tags: python

So if i use

```
tail 'path'
```

to view last few lines of text file I get 9 lines of data in this format:

```
20-3-2015 16:7:13 6
```

I use

```
splitted = file_open(name).rstrip().split(" ");
```

where the file_open function is

```
def file_open(name):
    f_name = prefix + name;
    offs = -10;
    with open(f_name, 'r') as f: # Open file to read
        while True:
            f.seek(offs,2) # Jump to final line and go to point in line to begin
            lines = f.readlines();
            if len(lines) >= 2:
                    return lines[-1]
            offs *= 2;
```

This should open file, go to last line return the full last line and then split up the three columns.

Instead the value of splitted is

```
['\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00']
```

whereas it should obviously be the final line. I have been using this code perfectly fine but all of a sudden I am getting this issue.

Comment: don't use `;`. this is unnecessary.

Comment: It's just habit from programming in other language

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136168/get-last-n-lines-of-a-file-with-python-similar-to-tail ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `seek` for text files and `readlines` with binary files. The behavior is not defined. `readlines` can use internal buffers. Some systems behave awkward, if you seek below 0 or larger than the file.

Comment: Could you suggest another method of finding the last line line of a text file?  It is either that or my other option is to just create another file with only 1 line of text. I want to read the line and display certain data on an LCD display